# How can i avoid duplicate key in joining tables in a one-many relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 6 tables that i am trying to query but i am getting duplicate primary keys in the query result. Here are the tables :

**userarticles**

```
id nomarticles 
 1 escarpin_estelle
 2 Tallon_grace
```

**articlesize**

```
productid  idsizes
 1          1
 1          2
 2          3
 2          5
```

**sizes**

```
idsizes size
  1       36
  2       38
  3       40
  4       44
  5       32
```

**articlematieres**

```
id_article id_matiere
  1          2
  1          1
  2          3
  2          3
```

**matiere**

```
matiereid  matierename
 1          daim
 2          coton
 3          polyster
```

**article_imgs**

```
imageid articleID filenames
  1       1       rouge2017-10-03.jpg   
  2       1       2017-10-03-204220.jpg
  3       2       moulante201.jpg
  4       2       avec-decollete.jpg
```

**The desire result should be to have**

```
id  articlename        size   filenames                            matiere 
 1  escarpin_estelle   38,45  rouge2017-10-03.jpg,moulante201.jpg  coton,daim
```

Here ismy query :

```
SELECT id,nomarticle,filenames,size,matierename FROM userarticles AS products LEFT JOIN article_imgs AS images ON images.articleID = products.id LEFT JOIN articlesize AS prodt ON prodt.idarticle = products.id LEFT JOIN sizes AS s ON s.idsizes = prodt.idsize LEFT JOIN articlematieres AS prodmat ON prodmat.id_article = products.id LEFT JOIN matiere AS m ON m.matiereid = prodmat.id_matiere WHERE products.id = 1
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: @pcdev i am using Mysql

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/276949/2869344) to see if it helps.  I think you are looking for the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function, but I'm not experienced with MySQL, sorry.

Comment: There is no sample data as per desire output. Could correct your sample data and expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

You **really** do have multiple answers:

`products.id` = 1 has 2 images, 2  sizes and 2 matiere

You really can't get a unique answer unless you specify more fields in your `WHERE`

** --- OPTIONALLY --- **

You can add `LIMIT 1` to your query to get the first one, but it's probably wrong.