# MYSQL query for concatenating values (highcharts series data)

Tags: mysql, highcharts

Im trying to make query for concatenating values (C) based on type (B) and date (A). If there is no record of B for day I need to put 0 value in concatenated value. Like in example below

```
+------------+---------+--------+
| A          | B       | C      |
+------------+---------+--------+
| 2017-10-20 | 001     |      1 |
| 2017-10-20 | 002     |      2 |
| 2017-10-21 | 003     |      3 |
| 2017-10-21 | 001     |      4 |
| 2017-10-21 | 002     |      1 |
| 2017-10-22 | 002     |      2 |
| 2017-10-22 | 003     |      2 |
| 2017-10-23 | 001     |      4 |
| 2017-10-23 | 002     |      6 |
| 2017-10-24 | 003     |      1 |
+------------+---------+--------+


+------------+-----------+
| B          | CONCAT    |
+------------+-----------+
| 001        | 1,4,0,4,0 |
| 002        | 2,1,2,6,0 |
| 003        | 0,3,2,0,1 |
+------------+-----------+
```

But I'm stuck, I need a solution. thank you

The essential problem is to insert 0 if the data for specific date does not exist, in date order

For 001(B) there is 2017-10-20(A) - 1(C), 2017-10-21(A) - 4(C), **2017-10-22(A) - 0(C)**, 2017-10-23(A) - 4(C), **2017-10-24(A) - 0(C)**,

```
SELECT b, 
       Group_concat(c ORDER BY b.a) 
FROM   pom2 a 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT a 
                  FROM   pom2 
                  GROUP  BY a) b 
              ON a.a = b.a 
GROUP  BY a.b
```

Returns this without zeros

```
+-----+------------------------------+
| B   | GROUP_CONCAT(C ORDER BY b.A) |
+-----+------------------------------+
| 001 | 1,4,4                        |
| 002 | 2,1,2,6                      |
| 003 | 3,2,1                        |
+-----+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Have a look at group_concat

Comment: Hint:  GROUP_CONCAT(C ORDER BY A)  and GROUP BY B.. plus this question is asked alot on stackoverflow.

Comment: @DusanKrstic do you want the query to add `0` values for the dates on which there is no entry? In that case, you will need another table with all the dates and do the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Yes Darshan, can you make query? Please

Comment: SELECT B,GROUP_CONCAT(C ORDER BY A) FROM `pom2` a LEFT JOIN (SELECT A FROM pom2 GROUP BY A) b ON a.A=b.A GROUP BY a.B but response is "Column 'A' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Comment: Put `b.A` inside group_concat and add the result of that query in your question.

Comment: And you want to solve all this in SQL? :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done :)

```
SELECT b, 
       Group_concat(c ORDER BY b.a) 
FROM   (SELECT a.a, 
               a.b, 
               Coalesce(b.c, 0) AS C 
        FROM   (SELECT b.a, 
                       a.b, 
                       0 AS C 
                FROM   pom2 a 
                       CROSS JOIN (SELECT a 
                                   FROM   pom2 
                                   GROUP  BY a) b) a 
               LEFT JOIN pom2 b 
                      ON a.a = b.a 
                         AND a.b = b.b 
        GROUP  BY a.b, 
                  a.a) a 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT a 
                  FROM   pom2 
                  GROUP  BY a) b 
              ON a.a = b.a 
GROUP  BY a.b
```

And result is:

```
+-----+------------------------------+
| b   | Group_concat(c ORDER BY b.a) |
+-----+------------------------------+
| 001 | 1,4,0,4,0                    |
| 002 | 2,1,2,6,0                    |
| 003 | 0,3,2,0,1                    |
+-----+------------------------------+
```