# concatenate similar rows into one MYSQL

Tags: mysql

i have for example 40 rows like

```
|name | type | addr_index | numbers |
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 john  1       46001       1,2,3 
 doe   1       67002       1,2,3 
 john  2       67002       10,22,34
 john  2       67002       7,4,3,2
```

How can i select rows with same data(name,type,addr_index), and concatenate **numbers** column to one row? like

```
|name | type | addr_index | numbers |
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 john  1       46001       1,2,3 
 doe   1       67002       1,2,3 
 john  2       67002       1,2,3,10,22,34
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field?rq=1

Comment: what if name is different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)**

**Syntax**

```
GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] expr [,expr ...]
         [ORDER BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | expr}
             [ASC | DESC] [,col_name ...]]
         [SEPARATOR str_val])
```

By default the separator is `,`. If you need another separator apart from comma, then you can give it by,

```
GROUP_CONCAT(expr separator 'char');
```

**Query**

```
SELECT `name`, `type`, `addr_index `,
GROUP_CONCAT(`numbers`)
FROM `your_table_name`
GROUP BY `name`, `type`, `addr_index `;
```

Comment: what if name or type is different? i need compare first name type, addr_index and then concatenate data that mathed

Answer (score 1):

you can use group concat

```
select name, type , addr_index , group_concat( numbers )
from my_table 
group by name, type , addr_index
```