# how to return multi- value columns in sql which is group by another column

Tags: mysql

How to return multi- value columns in sql which is group by another column. I have a table that contain question_id and competency_id.what i want is to return all the question_id as a single column based on competency id.

```
 c_id = [1,2,1,2,3,1];
q_id=[20,21,23,26,24,25];
```

what i want

```
expected = [{c_id:1,q_id:[20,23,25]},{c_id:2,q_id:[21,26]},{c_id:3,q_id:[21,26]}];
```

what i tried

```
select c_id, q_id from table group by c_id;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Comment: no its not the case of concatenation as i want to group my table according to c_id and list all the q_id belong to particular c_id

Comment: Please include proper sample data, table definitions and expected output in your question