# Mysql combine two rows into a single column

Tags: mysql, t-sql

I am attempting to combine two rows into a single column on mysql this is getting all two players in 1 single query and combine them using the team column, my table is below.

```
+-------------------+
| ID  player  Team  |
+-------------------+
| 1  John Doe Team1 |
| 2  Anna Doe Team1 |
+-------------------+
```

What I want to achieve is below.

```
+-----------------------------+
| ID  player1  player2  Team  |
+-----------------------------+
| 1  John Doe  Anna Doe Team1 |
+-----------------------------+
```

I am using PHP as my backend and doing a loop and pushing into a single array can do the job but I believe it can be attained using mysql query. any suggestion would be great.

Comment: Will there only be two players?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field?rq=1

Comment: why do you want to do this ? this will kill flexibility, in case you have more than 2 players in a team.

Comment: Define 'Player 1'. Define 'Player 2'. Also, it's much better to do this kind of thing in application code, as you're already doing!

Comment: @MichałTurczyn yes only two players per team

Comment: @DenisAlimov `GROUP_CONCAT` is not working on mysql version that I am using looks like i need to upgrade to use the answer link you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select team, 
       min(player) player1, 
       max(player) player2 
from my_table
group by team
```

Since there are only two players per team, `min` and `max` will return the two.

Comment: Agreed, this will work just fine if there are just two players per team.