# MariaDB SELECT multiple rows as single row

Tags: mysql, mariadb

How do I `SELECT` multiple rows of the same data (same table) as a single row?

Use case: I'm building a contacts management tool. Some people may have multiple email addresses and/or phone numbers. Instead of having to *manually* add yet another `LEFT JOIN` and return something such as the following:

```
//print_r($row1);
//email1, email2, email3, email4, phone1, phone2, phone3, phone4
```

I would prefer to have MariaDB return something visually along the lines of the following:

```
//print_r($row1);
//email, phone

//print_r($row1['email']);
//1@example.com,2@example.com,3@example.com

//print_r($row1['phone']);
//123-4567,456-7890,109-345
```

This would allow me to avoid static `JOIN`s. How can this be accomplished using MariaDB?

---

A great example is SQL Server's [`STUFF` function](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function I needed is `group_concat()`.

**Before**

```
SELECT phone FROM contacts_phone;
```

- 123
- 456
- 789

**After**

```
SELECT group_concat(phone) FROM contacts_phone;
```

- 123,456,789

Comment: You could also specify the separator inside the `GROUP_CONCAT` if you don't want the results to be separated by commas. For example `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(phone SEPARATOR ' ')` will return value as following `123 456 789` and  `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(phone SEPARATOR ';')` will return value as following `123;456;789` depending on your preference.

Comment: @tcadidot0 Nice! While I'm perfectly happy with the default delimiter being a comma it's nice to have the option to change it! Thank you very much!