# How to Concat results without duplicates when using "Like"

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to adapt the following query so that in Concats the results without any duplicates.

```
SELECT `increment_id`
FROM `sales_order`
WHERE `remote_ip`
LIKE '123.123.123.123'
```

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field), I have adapted the query to the following:

```
SELECT `remote_ip`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `increment_id` SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM `sales_order`
GROUP BY `remote_ip`
```

However, I'm struggling to find a place to add `LIKE '123.123.123.123'` without causing an error.

Comment: It seems like you simply need to add `WHERE remote_ip LIKE '123.123.123.123'` between your `FROM ...` and `GROUP BY ..` clauses.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya That appears to have done the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add the `WHERE` condition after your `FROM` clause, to filter the data accordingly:

```
SELECT `remote_ip`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `increment_id` SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM `sales_order`
WHERE `remote_ip` LIKE '123.123.123.123'
GROUP BY `remote_ip`
```