# Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows Group into one field?

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL, I can do something like:

```
SELECT sum(capacity) FROM table_name GROUP BY HOUR(time) ;
```

My Output:

```
1240
987
1092
1205
```

but instead I just want 1 row, 1 col:

Expected Output:

```
1240, 987, 1092, 1205
```

Comment: Research [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) , pretty sure that is what you are asking here..

Comment: Your question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field) one.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code - Note that in your example, you have no way of knowing which sum belongs to which hour.

Comment: to add to @Strawberry 's comment also the results are most likely different between MySQL 5 and MySQL 8 as MySQL 8 has removed implict `GROUP BY` sorting as it was deprecated since MySQL 5.7.. Also meaning that this will result into non deterministic ("random") sorting results on MySQL 8

Answer (score 0):

You could use group concat on your result

```
  SELECT group_concat(my_sum)
  from  (
    select  sum(capacity) my_sum
    FROM table_name 
    GROUP BY HOUR(time) 
    ORDER BY Hour(time)
  ) t
```

Comment: Note: MySQL 8 has removed implict `GROUP BY` sorting as it was deprecated since MySQL 5.7.. Also meaning that this will result into non deterministic ("random") sorting results on MySQL 8.. So this might need to have a `ORDER BY`

Comment: Well `ORDER BY Hour(time)` can still cause non deterministic ("random") sorting results if the values "ties"  forgot to mention... You will need to add atleast one deterministic  column to the `ORDER BY`, meaning the column must have a primary or unique key to get pure 100% deterministic (fixed) result on every run.