# Is there a MySQL function to pull data from multiple cells into one

Tags: mysql

I am trying to pull data from multiple cells into one. A device can be in multiple device groups and device groups can have multiple devices.

The first table looks as follows:

[image: First table]

The second table looks as follows:

[image: Second table]

The output should look as follows:

```
DID | DGID
12  | 342,543,100,132
45  | 342,678,987,100
```

Could someone please assist me with this?

Comment: Serializing datas goes against the purpose of using a RDBMS and you'll have to do the opposite operation to handle datas, deserializing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use `GROUP BY` and concatenation functions. If this is that useful is another question.

Example:

```sql
SELECT 
  did,
  GROUP_CONCAT(dgid SEPARATOR ', ') as dgid
FROM
  table1
  LEFT JOIN table2
GROUP BY
  did
```

See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-group_concat-function/

Comment: That's great. You may consider mark it as correct answer.