# One to many query - SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm working with 3 table. `Driver`,  `Car`,  and `Garage`. Garage is a `1 to N` relationship table between `Driver` and `Car` (One driver has at least one car)

```
Driver Table
╔════╦══════╗
║ ID ║ Name ║
╠════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ Edson║
║  2 ║ Tomas║
║  3 ║ Carry║
╚════╩══════╩

Car Table
╔════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ Brand  ║
╠════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ Ferrari║
║  2 ║ Porche ║
║  3 ║ McLaren║
╚════╩════════╩
Garage Table
╔════╦═════════╗═══════
║ ID ║Driver.Id║Car.Id║
╠════╬═════════╣═══════
║  1 ║ 1       ║  1   ║
║  2 ║ 2       ║  2   ║
║  3 ║ 2       ║  3   ║
║  4 ║ 3       ║  2   ║
╚════╩═════════╩═══════
```

I need get a Drivers list  with your cars. Something like this:

```
[Edson, [Ferrari]]
[Tomas, [Porche, McLaren]]
[Carry, [Porche ]]
```

I already tried the code below, but I didn't get the expected result.

```
connection.execute(db.select([Driver.Name, Car.Brand]).where(Garage.Driver.Id == Driver.ID and Garage.Car.Id == Car.ID)).fetchall()
```

So, how can I make JOIN query to get the expected results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_concat` as shown below.

data input:

```
#drop table if exists driver;
create table driver (id int(11), name varchar(255));
insert into driver (id, name) values (1, 'Edson');
insert into driver (id, name) values (2, 'Tomas');
insert into driver (id, name) values (3, 'Carry');

#drop table if exists car;
create table car (id int(11), brand varchar(255));
insert into car (id, brand) values (1, 'Ferrari');
insert into car (id, brand) values (2, 'Porsche');
insert into car (id, brand) values (3, 'McLaren');

#drop table if exists garage;
create table garage (id int(11), driver_id int(11), car_id int(11));
insert into garage (id, driver_id, car_id) values (1, 1, 1);
insert into garage (id, driver_id, car_id) values (2, 2, 2);
insert into garage (id, driver_id, car_id) values (3, 2, 3);
insert into garage (id, driver_id, car_id) values (4, 3, 2);
```

solution:

```
select d.name, group_concat(c.brand separator ', ')
from driver d
left join garage g on d.id = g.driver_id
left join car c on g.car_id = c.id
group by d.id;
```

You can also check here where the approach is dealt with in great lengths: 
[Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field/276949#276949)