# Is it possible to concatenate all string values that meet a condition into in one column with MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `geos` which has two columns. `geoName` which is a string description of a physical area which is outlined by the spatial Polygon in the `geoPoly` column. Each record is either a country or a city which may be in one of those countries.

For each geoName, I want to get a list of the names of all intersecting polygons into a single column.

So if `geos` looks like this:

| geoName | geoPoly |
| --- | --- |
| Mumbai | Polygon1 |
| Chennai | Polygon2 |
| New York | Polygon3 |
| United States | Polygon4 |
| India | Polygon5 |
| Paris | Polygon6 |
| Chicago | Polygon7 |
| Los Angeles | Polygon7 |

Using the query below, I'm able to get a table that returns just one result in the intersectingGeo column.

```
SELECT geos1.geoName AS targetGeo, geos2.geoName AS intersectingGeo
FROM geos geos1, geos geos2
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(geos1.geoPoly, geos2.geoPoly)
AND geos1.geoName <> geos2.geoName
GROUP BY targetGeo
```

Which outputs:

| geoName | intersectingGeo |
| --- | --- |
| Mumbai | India |
| Chennai | India |
| New York | United States |
| India | Mumbai |
| Chicago | United States |
| Chicago | Los Angeles |

But is it possible to get a concatenated list of the geoNames of all intersecting Polygons, like this?

| geoName | geoPoly |
| --- | --- |
| Mumbai | India |
| Chennai | India |
| New York | United States |
| **United States** | **New York, Chicago, Los Angeles** |
| **India** | **Chennai, Mumbai** |
| Chicago | United States |

All of the CONCAT examples I can find have just one

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer 30 seconds after posting. Obviously.

GROUP_CONCAT()

```
SELECT geos1.geoName AS targetGeo, GROUP_CONCAT(geos2.geoName SEPARATOR ', ') AS intersectingGeo
FROM geos geos1, geos geos2
WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(geos1.geoPoly, geos2.geoPoly)
AND geos1.geoName <> geos2.geoName
GROUP BY targetGeo
```

Works perfectly.

[Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)