# In Google BigQuery SQL, how to concatenate rows of string for same person?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, concatenation

I need to use Google Cloud Platform to write my SQL codes. One problem I currently have writing the SQL query is, there is not much option to choose for concatenating strings.

For example, if my database is like this:

```
ID       Location
1        NY
1        TN
1        NC
2        FL
2        UK
3        MN
```

I hope to get a new table like this, which have a unique ID with a location column listed all the places the person went.

```
ID    Loc
1     NY, TN, NC
2     FL, UK
3     MN
```

I know in Mysql, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT`(see post: [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)) or `FOR XML PATH` (see post: [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv/42778050#42778050), but it seems like I can only use a limited function in the BigQuery.

Does anyone have some suggestions for solving this? Any thought is helpful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In BigQuery, you would use `string_agg()`:

```
select id, string_agg(location, ', ' order by location) as locations
from t
group by id;
```

However, in BigQuery, you would normally use arrays for this:

```
select id, array_agg(location order by location)
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Wow! That is really helpful. Thanks for the quick answer. I found exactly what I am looking for. I also see why your suggestion of array_agg, which return the result in a separate row but under the same ID name and a lot faster. Thanks!