# How to solve 'Subquery returns more than 1 row' in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables like below:

users: (id,name)

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Arthur |

images: (id,user_id,path,createdAt)

| id | user_id | path | createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | image_path | 2021-07-11 05:38:15 |
| 2 | 1 | image_path | 2021-07-10 05:38:15 |
| 3 | 1 | image_path | 2021-07-9 05:38:15 |
| 4 | 1 | image_path | 2021-07-8 05:38:15 |

follow: (id,followee,follower)

| id | followee | follower |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |

What I want: A SQL query to get all followee's names, total images, and most recent 3 images(id and path) for a specific follower.

```
[
   {
        "name": "John",
        "total_images": 1,
        "recent_images": [
            {
                "id": 154,
                 "path": "image_path"
            },
            {
                "id": 125,
                "path": "image_path"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I have tried:

```sql
SELECT users.name

 (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT images.id)
  FROM images
  WHERE images.user_id = follow.followee
 ) AS "total_images",

 (SELECT images.id , images.path
  FROM images
  WHERE images.user_id = follow.followee
  ORDER BY images.createdAt DESC
  LIMIT 3
 ) AS "recent_images"

FROM follow
LEFT JOIN users ON followers.followee = users.id
WHERE follow.follower = 2
```

Server type: MySQL ; Server version: 8.0.27

ERROR:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Move the subqueries to the FROM clause.

Comment: mysql ? sqlserver ? which one ?

Comment: You cannot use statement  like this in inner query which selects 3 records ...  also any desired result will help alot

Comment: see: [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Comment: @pilchard Thank you,what I understand from your given reference is that I can concatenate a single column in one column but can I do it for multiple columns? Like images.id and images.path

Answer (score 2):

The second subquery in `SELECT` returns more than 1 row; which is invalid in `SELECT`. I see in you latest edit you've added another column. That's going to give you another different error of:

> Error 1241: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

With your current query, you probably can do it like this:

```
SELECT users.name,

 (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT images.id)
  FROM images
  WHERE images.user_id = follow.followee
 ) AS "total_images",

 (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(images.id ,': ', images.path)) AS 'image_and_path'
  FROM images
  WHERE images.user_id = follow.followee
  ORDER BY images.createdAt DESC
  LIMIT 3
 ) AS "recent_images"

FROM follow
LEFT JOIN users ON follow.followee = users.id
WHERE follow.follower = 2;
```

That will give you results like:

| name | total_images | recent_images |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 4 | 1: image_path,2: image_path,3: image_path,4: image_path |

One row with a concatenated columns + a `GROUP_CONCAT()` from the second subquery in `SELECT`.

Otherwise, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT u1.name AS 'Followee',
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY f.follower) Total_images,
       createdAt
FROM users u1 
JOIN images i ON u1.id=i.user_id
JOIN follow f ON u1.id=f.followee
WHERE f.follower=2
ORDER BY createdAt DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

With this results:

| Followee | Total_images | id | path | createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 4 | 1 | image_path | 2021-07-11 05:38:15 |
| John | 4 | 2 | image_path | 2021-07-10 05:38:15 |
| John | 4 | 3 | image_path | 2021-07-09 05:38:15 |

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=19546204f09e230a485c84611a7d9cdf)

Update:

To make the value recognizable as JSON array and object, you can add combinations of `JSON_OBJECT` and `JSON_ARRAY`. Here's [MySQL functions that create JSON values docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html):

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT('name',name,'total_images',total_images,'recent_images',
           JSON_ARRAY(GROUP_CONCAT(recent_images))))
FROM
(SELECT u.name ,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY f.follower) AS total_images,
        JSON_OBJECT('id',i.id,'path',i.path) recent_images
FROM follow f
JOIN users u ON f.followee = u.id
JOIN images i ON i.user_id = f.followee
WHERE f.follower = 2
ORDER BY i.createdAt DESC
LIMIT 3) AS V
GROUP BY name, total_images
```

If `LIMIT` is not working for you (probably due to `sql_mode`? I'm not sure), then I'd suggest you use `ROW_NUMBER()` (or `RANK()`) function to assign the value with incremental numbering from 1 - XX in descending order. Here's how:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT('name',name,'total_images',total_images,'recent_images',
           JSON_ARRAY(GROUP_CONCAT(recent_images))))
FROM
(SELECT u.name ,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY f.follower) AS total_images,
        JSON_OBJECT('id',i.id,'path',i.path) recent_images,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f.follower ORDER BY i.createdAt DESC) rn
FROM follow f
JOIN users u ON f.followee = u.id
JOIN images i ON i.user_id = f.followee
WHERE f.follower = 2) AS V
WHERE rn <= 3
GROUP BY name, total_images;
```

[Updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2967916957dfd86988108656089e5936)

Comment: Thank you, your first solution gives me a string field but I want array of objects. Is there any way? Another point is LIMIT  is not working.

Comment: The part where LIMIT is not working, does it return any error message? About formatting the results as array, I'll get back to you on that.

Answer (score 0):

I have inserted the records in images as follows:

| id | user_id | path | createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | image_path | 2021-07-11 05:38:15 |
| 2 | 2 | image_path | 2021-07-11 05:38:16 |
| 3 | 2 | image_path | 2021-07-11 05:38:17 |
| 4 | 2 | image_path | 2021-07-11 05:38:18 |
| 5 | 1 | image_path | 2021-07-11 05:38:19 |
| 6 | 1 | image_path | 2021-07-11 05:38:20 |

So your SQL result should return multiple rows for the recent 3 images of every follower of an individual followee. Here the SQL query with additional columns those you can omit later:

```
SELECT users.name AS followee, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM images WHERE images.user_id = follow.followee) AS total_images, images.user_id AS followerId, (SELECT users.name FROM users WHERE id = follow.follower) AS followerName, images.id AS followerImgId, images.path FROM images JOIN follow ON follow.follower = images.user_id JOIN users ON follow.followee = users.id ORDER BY images.createdAt ASC LIMIT 0, 3;
```

| followee | total_images | followerId | followerName | followerImgId | path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2 | 2 | Arthur | 4 | image_path |
| John | 2 | 2 | Arthur | 3 | image_path |
| John | 2 | 2 | Arthur | 2 | image_path |

Now, to output the JSON array:

```
SELECT 
    JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT('name',name,'total_images',total_images,'recent_images',
    JSON_ARRAY(GROUP_CONCAT(recent_images))))
FROM
    (SELECT 
        users.name, 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM images WHERE images.user_id = follow.followee) AS total_images, 
        JSON_OBJECT ('id',images.id,'path',images.path) AS recent_images 
     FROM images 
     JOIN follow ON follow.follower = images.user_id 
     JOIN users ON follow.followee = users.id 
     ORDER BY images.createdAt ASC LIMIT 0, 3) SQL2JSON;
```

```js
[{"name": "John", "total_images": 2, "recent_images": ["{\"id\": 4, \"path\": \"image_path\"},{\"id\": 3, \"path\": \"image_path\"},{\"id\": 2, \"path\": \"image_path\"}"]}]
```

**N.B.:** You may need to perform few string replacements with the result JSON for removing any unnecessary double-quotes, back slashes etc.