# SQL concat IDs of rows after group by

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I'm trying to output a query that has a count of a group by but also, specifies the list of IDs in that row.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
    title,
    period,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    title, period
```

Example database

| Title | Period | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Title2 | MONTH | 321 |
| Title1 | DAY | 789 |
| Title1 | DAY | 123 |
| Title1 | MONTH | 123 |

Output

| Title | Period | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Title2 | MONTH | 1 |
| Title1 | DAY | 2 |
| Title1 | MONTH | 1 |

But I would like the output to be something like:

| Title | Period | COUNT(*) | Who? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Title2 | MONTH | 1 | 321 |
| Title1 | DAY | 2 | 123, 789 |
| Title1 | MONTH | 1 | 123 |

What do I need to add to my query to get this output? I've tried to use an `SELF JOIN` and a `SELECT JOIN`, but I cannot quite get the syntax right.

Comment: So you are looking for an aggregate string concatenation function, like STRING_AGGR in SQLServer or LIST in Firebird, but then for MySQL.

Comment: When pinned down & clearly expressed this will be a faq. (Clearly.) Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT
    title,
    period,
    COUNT(*),
    GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id SEPARATOR ', ') AS Who
FROM
    yourtable
GROUP BY
    title, period
ORDER BY title DESC;
```

Note: I don't know if the two `ORDER BY` clauses are necessary for you. I just added them to produce exactly your outcome. Remove them if not needed.

You can also remove the part `SEPARATOR ', '` if you don't require spaces after the commas.

Try out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TMibZSEB)

Here the documentation: [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat)