# Sql query for combining different status for item order id

Tags: sql, mysql

I have three columns

```
1.order_item_id where datatype is STRING,
2.delivered_date_time where datatype is TIMESTAMP ,
3.status where datatype is string ,
```

Write a sql query to combine the different status of particular order_item_id separated by semi-colon and first delivered_date_time of order_item_id should come first and
second delivered_date_time of order_item_id should come second and so on.

wrote a query with STRING_AGG and GROUP_CONCAT function but it is giving me below error -

Query validation failed

```
Syntax Validation: [PARSING] Error while parsing query line 3:25: no viable alternative at input 'SELECT\n order_item_id,\nSTRING_AGG(status, '; ' ORDER'
```

SQL Query:-

```
SELECT
  order_item_id,
 GROUP_CONCAT(status ORDER BY delivered_date_time ASC SEPARATOR '; ') as  status_list
//STRING_AGG(status, '; ' ORDER BY delivered_date_time ASC) AS status_list
FROM
  Order
GROUP BY
  order_item_id;
```

Can anyone please help me solving this issue?

Eg-

```
order_ITEM_ID   status  
1            UNDELIVERED  
1            IN_PROGRESS  
1            REJECTED  
1            ready_to_ship  
2            APPROVED  
2            on_hold  
2            null
```

output:-

```
  order_ITEM_ID status  
1   UNDELIVERED;IN_PROGRESS;REJECTED ;  ready_to_ship  
2   APPROVED;on_hold;null
```

Comment: What is your database?  MySQL?  SQL Server?  Something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I concatenate multiple MySQL rows into one field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field)

Comment: That error message doesn't look like it comes from MySQL.

Comment: The query uses `GROUP_CONCAT()`, but the error message says `STRING_AGG()`. It looks like you posted a different version of the query than the one you used. `GROUP_CONCAT()` should work in MySQL.

Comment: It is Sql databases .
Same error for both GROUP_CONCAT() and STRING_AGG(). i just posted one sample error msg

Comment: Study the syntax for `STRING_AGG`. You loose `WITHIN GROUP`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on SQL Server 2017 or higher then you have a choice of using the `STRING_AGG` function as follows:

```
STRING_AGG(status, '; ') 
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY delivered_date_time ASC) AS status_list
```

Before SQL Server 2017, We need to use `STUFF` function.

Refer [STRING_AGG documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for more details on the function

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether the database in question is `SQL Server` or `MySQL`.

**Using SQL Server :**

You can use `STRING_AGG` function to concatenate the statuses and order them based on the `delivered_date_time`.

```
SELECT 
    ID,
    STRING_AGG(status, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY delivered_date_time) AS status_combined
FROM 
    order_status
GROUP BY 
    ID
```

[See this **db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/4nS5rYHX).

**Using MySql :**

In MySQL by using the `GROUP_CONCAT` function to combine the statuses for each `ID` and ordering the statuses based on their `delivered_date_time`.

```
SELECT ID, GROUP_CONCAT(status ORDER BY delivered_date_time SEPARATOR ';') AS status
FROM order_status
GROUP BY ID;
```

[See this **db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/mogBMzCv).