Combine one column from multiple records in one cell
I have two tables:
orders:



id
customer




19
373


20
358



orderlines:



id
order_id
article_id




3
19
22


4
19
28


5
19
42


6
20
22


7
20
69



And I want to write a query for MySQL that returns this result:



id
customer
articles




19
373
22,28,42


20
358
22,69



I found solutions using STRING_AGG for SQL Server, but I need a query for MySQL.
Can anybody help me?

This question is similar to: Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION 577. employee bonus.string_agg does not exist. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You could have just searched on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276927/can-i-concatenate-multiple-mysql-rows-into-one-field

@JonasMetzler they didn't say they needed a solution for MS SQL, they said when they searched for a solution some of what they found was MS SQL/STRING_AGG (implying that is not what they want)

this is just select o.id,o.customer,group_concat(ol.article_id) articles from orders o join orderlines ol on ol.order_id=o.id or possibly group_concat(distinct ol.article_id)

@ysth After doing lots of changes on both question and answer, now people should be able to understand and replicate it. Maybe we can reopen the question (although I guess there are likely similar questions, so it could be a duplicate).

Join your two tables on id and use STRING_AGG or GROUP_CONCAT to get your articles column
TSQL
SELECT o.id,
       o.customer,
       STRING_AGG(ol.article_id,',') AS articles 
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN orderlines ol ON ol.order_id=o.id     
GROUP BY o.id, o.customer
ORDER BY o.id, o.customer;

MySQL uses GROUP_CONCAT:
SELECT o.id,
       o.customer,
       GROUP_CONCAT(ol.article_id) AS articles 
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN orderlines ol ON ol.order_id=o.id     
GROUP BY o.id, o.customer
ORDER BY o.id, o.customer;

See this sample fiddle with your data.

@Jonas Metzler thanks. I was focused on providing an example of STRING_AGG and GROUP_CONCAT. I assumed the rest of the query was obvious. Probably better if I provide complete SQL statements.
