# Merge rows into one TSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
ID | First Name | Last Name |
-----------------------------
1  | Test       | NULL      |
2  | Test       | ABC1      |
```

I need to merge these two rows into one to display as so the null in 'last name' will be replaced by the text in the second column, Grouping by the first name.

```
 ID | First Name | Last Name |
 -----------------------------
 1  | Test       | ABC1|
```

Comment: But what have you tried yourself?

Comment: But what you have *searched* for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in MS SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005). Or this http://stackoverflow.com/q/1874966/27535

Comment: Did any below answer made you feel happy ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select min (id),First_Name,MAX(Last_Name)
from your_table
group by First_Name
```