# Select multi value from another table and put in one string split by -

Tags: sql-server, select, view

I have 2 tables in MS SQL Server.

Table 1

```
ID   Name  
-------------
10   Series      
11   Movie      
12   Music      
13   Other
```

Table 2

```
ID    IDCatg    Value  
---------------------------
1       10          Hannibal
2       10          Blacklist
3       10          POI
4       11          Hitman
5       11          SAW
6       11          Spider man
7       12          taylor swift
8       12          britney spears
```

I want to select by IDCatg in Table 2 and create a new column in Table 1 like this:

```
IDCatg     Name        Value
--------------------------------------------
10         Series      Hannibal-Blacklist-POI
11         Movie       Hitman-SAW-Spider man
12         Music       taylor swift-britney spears
```

How can I do this by view?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate row values T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874966/concatenate-row-values-t-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `STUFF`:

```
SELECT T21.IDCatg, T1.Name,
      [Value] = STUFF((
          SELECT '-' + T22.[Value]
          FROM Table2 T22
          WHERE T21.IDCatg = T22.IDCatg
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM Table2 T21 JOIN 
     Table1 T1 ON T1.ID=T21.IDCatg
GROUP BY T21.IDCatg,T1.Name
```

Result:

```
IDCatg  Name    Value
---------------------------------------------
10      Series  Hannibal-Blacklist-POI
11      Movie   Hitman-SAW-Spider man
12      Music   taylor swift-britney spears
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/baca8/8)

**EDIT:**

When the type of `Value` is int, you can cast it to varchar:

```
  [Value] = STUFF((
      SELECT '-' + CAST(T22.[Value] AS Varchar(MAX))
```

Comment: Thank you , it works , but if my Value type is int , i get this error:
conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',' to data type int

Comment: generally when my value type is int , '-' doesn't work !
what i have to do

Comment: another question pls!
if i want to JOIN value to another table and replace value by other field in table 3 , how can i do that ?

Comment: @mosyflasher: Just replace `Table2` with the name of the new table and replace `Value` with the new field name.

Comment: i don't think this is true . because i need 3 table here . i mean this select that we did is true , now i want replace only value by joining to table 3 . example:
Hannibal-Blacklist-POI  =>  x-y-z

Comment: @mosyflasher: Edit your question and add the details. Then only I can understand and then I will be able to help you.

Comment: thanks dude , i could figure it out ;)
you helped so much