# Concatenate columns strings for matching rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concatenation

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    sys.objects.object_id, sys.objects.name, sys.objects.type_desc, 
    sys.syscomments.text
FROM 
    sys.objects
LEFT JOIN 
    sys.syscomments ON sys.syscomments.id = sys.objects.object_id
WHERE 
    (type_desc LIKE 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE' OR type_desc LIKE 'SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION')
ORDER BY 
    sys.objects.object_id;
```

Here is part of the output:

[image]

So how would I concatenate the 'text' columns for rows with the same 'object_id' so that I don't have duplicates ID? Not so simple in T-SQL without an aggregate function for strings...

I've seen other examples but I can't seem to get it working for my scenario.

Comment: Show us sample data as text *( we cant copy/paste from pictures)* and desire output.    Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
  
  And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The For XML Path method of doing a Concatenation aggregation is one of the more popular ways to do what you're looking to do here.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874966/concatenate-row-values-t-sql) for details.

An application to your situation might look like this:

```
SELECT B.object_id, B.name, B.type_desc, 
    STUFF((SELECT A.[text] 
                        FROM sys.syscomments AS A
                        WHERE A.id = B.[object_id]
                        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '' ) AS [text]
FROM 
    sys.objects AS B
WHERE type_desc LIKE 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE' OR type_desc LIKE 'SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION'
ORDER BY B.[object_id];
```

Comment: Yeah that works! But is there a way to not have all the XML markups included in the result?

Comment: got it by changing FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a function to concatenation:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTexts](@id INT)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @res NVARCHAR(4000)

    SELECT  DISTINCT
            @res =
            SUBSTRING(
            (
                SELECT  ',' + SC1.[text]
                FROM    dbo.syscomments SC1
                WHERE   SC1.id = SC2.id
                FOR     XML PATH ('')
            ), 2, 4000)
    FROM    dbo.syscomments SC2
    WHERE   SC2.id = @id

    RETURN @res
END
```

Then, execute the `SELECT` query.

```
SELECT  dbo.[objects].[object_id], dbo.[objects].name, dbo.[objects].type_desc, dbo.GetTexts([object_id])
FROM    dbo.[objects]
```

P.S.: I'm not sure about the schema names, so correct them as you want.