# how to select distinct and concatenate in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Lets say we have a following table with two columns and following rows of data  in SQLServer-2005:

```
Tiger    50
Wolf     4
Tiger    53
Lion     55
Elephant 54
Rhino    52
Lion     5
```

Can we have a sql query that result as following: `Tiger,Wolf,Lion,Elephant,Rhino` as a single string varchar output?Is it possible ?
using T-SQL not possible singe I am using the result in c# as a result of executescalar
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `for xml path` to concatenate the values:

```
select distinct name + ', ' as [text()]
from @t
for xml path('')

-->
Elephant, Lion, Rhino, Tiger, Wolf,
```

Chop of the last 2 bytes if you don't like trailing `,`'s.

Not sure why you can't use T-SQL, you can use this in combination with ExecuteScalar() just fine.

Sample data:

```
declare @t table (name varchar(max), id int)
insert into @t 
select 'Tiger', 50
union all select 'Wolf', 4
union all select 'Tiger', 53
union all select 'Lion', 55
union all select 'Elephant', 54
union all select 'Rhino', 52
union all select 'Lion', 5
```

Comment: @Andomar We could have any data in first column so could not hard-code it.

Comment: @Thunder: The second part is just your example data in T-SQL; the query with `for xml path` should work for any data

Comment: @Andomar I think its correct but I already have table with data ,can we link @t to an existing table?

Comment: @Thunder: Yeah, `@t` is just the name of my table variable (it's not a real table but a table variable, so it starts with @.)  You can replace `@t` with the name of your table

Comment: @Andomar Thanks Andomar ,It worked ! alo quite amazed this is very new to me.I have never come across "for xml path('')"  can u let us know what is this actually ,I am sure its not normal SQL

Comment: @Thunder: It's a construct meant for generating XML output.  To use it for generating comma-seperated lists is something of a trick; it wasn't designed for that.  You can find more about the intended uses here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190922.aspx

Answer (score 1):

See [**How to return multiple values in one column (T-SQL)?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122942/how-to-return-multiple-values-in-one-column-t-sql)

Comment: using T-SQL not possible singe I am using the result in c# as a result of executescalar

Comment: @Thunder, that doesn't make any sense, the only requirement for `ExecuteScalar` is that there is only one result.  There is no restriction whatsoever on what the SQL looks like before the final `SELECT`.  I'm upvoting this one.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting this from ExecuteScalar and using the resulting composite string in C#, then you are going to end up writing a sproc, or just having your code work with the datatable.

Can you provide more detail on why you can't use a sproc?  A few good examples have been provided that would do fine with that, and you can still get your scalar result

Comment: Sored procedure could not be written as it would increase more process in deployment as we will have to add sproc to db manually

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP_CONCAT() with DISTINCT:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT colName) FROM tblName;
```

Comment: @Crozin I think your answer is near to solution but GROUP_CONCAT was not recognised ,Please note that we are using sqlserver2005

Comment: Group_concat works in MySQL, but the question is about SQL Server

Comment: downvoting this because the example is in the wrong SQL dialect, and should not have been upvoted.

Comment: Oh, my bad... I didn't noticed it's about sql-server-2005.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is probably to use a [User-Defined Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165055(VS.80).aspx), but you can also abuse the `UPDATE` statement:

```
DECLARE @Result varchar(500)
SET @Result = ''

UPDATE Animals
    SET @Result = @Result + Name + ','

SELECT @Result
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how Andomar's Answer was implemented.Thanks to Andomar's answer got to learn some thing new with this .

> select distinct summaryColumn + ', '
>   as [text()] from tablename for
>   xml path('')