# Nested SELECT statement in a CASE expression

Tags: select, case, coalesce

Greetings,

Here is my problem.
I need to get data from multiple rows and return them as a single result in a larger query.

I already posted a similar question here.
[Return multiple values in one column within a main query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412381/return-multiple-values-in-one-column-within-a-main-query) but I suspect my lack of SQL knowledge made the question too vague because the answers did not work.
I am using Microsoft SQL 2005.
Here is what I have.

Multiple tables with CaseID as the PK, CaseID is unique.
One table (tblKIN) with CaseID and ItemNum(AutoInc) as the combined PK.
Because each person in the database will likely have more than one relative.
If I run the following, in a SQL query window, it works.

```
DECLARE @KINList varchar(1000)  
SELECT @KINList = coalesce(@KINList + ', ','') + KINRel from tblKIN  
WHERE CaseID = 'xxx' and Address = 'yyy'  
ORDER BY KINRel  
SELECT @KINList
```

This will return the relation of all people who live at the same address. the results look like this...
Father, Niece, Sister, Son

Now, the problem for me is how do I add that to my main query?
Shortened to relevant information, the main query looks like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
c.CaseID,  
c.Name,  
c.Address,  
Relatives=CASE WHEN exists(select k.CaseID from tblKIN k where c.CaseID = k.CaseID)  
   THEN DECLARE @KINList varchar(1000)  
        SELECT @KINList = coalesce(@KINList + ', ','') + KINRel from tblKIN  
        WHERE CaseID = 'xxx' and Address = 'yyy'  
        ORDER BY KINRel  
        SELECT @KINList  
   ELSE ''  
   END
FROM tblCase c  
ORDER BY c.CaseID
```

The errors I receive are.
Server: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.
Server: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

I tried nesting inside parenthesis from the DECLARE to the end of the SELECT @KINList.
I tried adding a BEGIN and END to the THEN section of the CASE statement.
Neither worked.

The source table data looks something like this. (***periods added for readability***)
tblCase
CaseID  Name   Address
10-001  Jim......100 Main St.
10-002  Tom....150 Elm St.
10-003  Abe.....200 1st St.

tblKIN
CaseID  ItemNum  Name  Relation  Address
10-001 00001   Steve...Son........100 Main St.
10-002 00002   James..Father....150 Elm St.
10-002 00003   Betty....Niece......150 Elm St.
10-002 00004   Greta...Sister.....150 Elm St.
10-002 00005   Davey..Son........150 Elm St.
10-003 00006   Edgar...Brother...200 1st St.

If I run the query for CaseID = 10-002, it needs to return the following.
CaseID Name Address.......Relatives
10-002  Tom...150 Elm St. ..Father, Niece, Sister, Son

I am sure this is probably a simple fix, but I just don't know how to do it.
Thank you for your time, and I apologize for the length of the question, but I wanted to be clear.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I did something similar I had to create a scalar function to do the coalesce that returns the varchar result.  Then just call it in the select.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetRelatives 
(
    @CaseID varchar(10)
)
RETURNS varchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @KINList varchar(1000)  
    SELECT @KINList = coalesce(@KINList + ', ','') + KINRel from tblKIN  
        WHERE CaseID = @CaseID  
    ORDER BY KINRel  

    RETURN @KINList 

END
```

Then your select

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
c.CaseID,  
c.Name,  
c.Address,  
database.dbo.GetRelatives(c.CaseID) AS Relatives
FROM tblCase c  
ORDER BY c.CaseID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `FUNCTION` which takes in the `caseID` as the arguement and returns `true` or `false`.

Since you are calling the nested query multiple times, its definitely a performance hit. A better solution is to execute the query and store the results in a temporary table.
Then pass this temporary table and the `caseID` to the `FUNCTION` and check for containment.