# Multiple Resources with multiple names

Tags: sql, grouping, concatenation

Sorry if this may seem simple, maybe it's Friday and my brain just isn't working. I have been trying to figure out the best way to handle a problem for 4 or so hours and can't come up with the best answer. Hopefully you guys can help me out. I am working with MSSQL

I need to concatenate these "Names" as a single string delimited by commas. And only show the single ID.   ie.. |ID1 | name1,name2,name3|.

I have never done this and cannot locate the resources to figure it out. I am sure there is some way you can coalesce it, but I can't figure it out. Thanks for your time in advance.

### **ID               NAME**

ID1              NAME1

ID1              NAME2

ID1              NAME3

ID2              NAME2

ID2              NAME3

ID3              NAME1

ID4              NAME2

SELECT s2._ResourceGuid, s2.SoftwareCount, s2.RPMList
FROM (SELECT rpm._ResourceGuid,count(rpm.name) AS SoftwareCount, (???????) as SoftwareList
      FROM Inv_Unix_RPMInfo rpm WITH (NOLOCK)
      WHERE rpm.Name ='VRTSvxvm' 
            OR rpm.Name = 'VRTSvxfs'
            OR rpm.Name = 'VRTSvcs' 
      GROUP BY _ResourceGuid 
)s2

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122942/how-to-return-multiple-values-in-one-column-t-sql

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a great non-standard function for this called [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). I found a few articles on how to do this in MSSQL with a quick googling. Here's one now:

[How to return multiple values in one column (T-SQL)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122942/how-to-return-multiple-values-in-one-column-t-sql)

Comment: Thanks for the help.. Sorry I didn't use the resources available.

Comment: @Justin, no problems. Glad I could help either way ;)