# How to write a stored procedure for this code

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, split

I have a table `Companiesdata`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Companiesdata]
(
[Company Name] nvarchar(255),
[Industry] varchar(40),
[ParentId] int NULL,
)
```

and the rows are

```
CompanyName               Industry          Parent ID  
--------------------------------------------------------
Xyz technologies          Software             1
apple Technologies        software             1
Sun network               media                2
abc Technologies          advertising          4
PQR Technnologies         Marketing            5
abc Technologies          Media                4
```

I have another table

```
create table dbo.companiesss
(
autoid int identity(1,1),
companyname varchar(max),
Industry  varchar(max)
)
```

I wrote a procedure like this:

```
create proc pr_getlistofcompaniesss (@tparentid varchar(20))   
as 
begin
   insert into dbo.companiesss(companyname, industry) 
      select  
          [CompanyName], [Industry] 
      from 
          [Companiesdata]
      where 
          parentid in (select items from dbo.split(@tparentid,',')) 
      except
      select company name, industry 
      from dbo.companiesss 
end
```

The output is as below:

```
pr_getlistofcompaniesss 1,2,4
```

the rows are displayed as

```
AutoID    Company name              Industry
---------------------------------------------------
  1       apple Technologies        software
  2       Sun network               Media
  3       xyz Technologies          software
  4       abc Technologies          advertising
  5       abc technologies          media
```

instead my output should be as below:

```
pr_getlistofcompaniesss 1,2,4

AutoID    Company name              Industry
---------------------------------------------------
  1       apple Technologies        software
  2       Sun network               Media
  3       xyz Technologies          software
  4       abc Technologies          advertising,media
```

i.e if I have the same company (here `abc technologies`) with different industries name, then the industry field should be separated with comma displaying the record on same row i.e (`advertising, media`)

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405362/concatenate-multiple-rows-from-multiple-tables you have 2 options there - use XML, or create an aggregate CLR function

Comment: Or, since this looks like prepared data for a report, move the presentation work to the reporting engine, where it belongs. In short: the result you obtain is correct, you should group values together in your report, not in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a scalar function to achieve similar results, and then cross apply the function your stored procedure.  Code is below:

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[fnListIndustry] (@ParentID varchar(10))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN 
DECLARE @IndustryList   varchar(1000)
SELECT  @IndustryList   = COALESCE(@IndustryList + ',', '') + rtrim(dbo.Companiesdata.Industry)
FROM    dbo.Companiesdata 
WHERE   dbo.Companiesdata.parenid = @ParentID

RETURN  @IndustryList
END
```

Comment: Beware of scalar functions that use `select` queries.  Depending on the size of tables your dealing with, performance can be severely impacted

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to pass in those IDs together in a string, not as separate parameters.  Your procedure only accepts one parameter.

```
pr_getlistofcompaniesss '1,2,4'
```

Then in your procedure, update your insert clause to below.  That will concatenate the industries into one string delimited by commas.

```
insert into dbo.companiesss(companyname,industry) 
select [CompanyName],
       STUFF((select distinct ',' + [Industry]
              from [Companiesdata] as child
              where child.parentid = parent.parentid
              for xml path ('')),
             1, 2, '')
from [Companiesdata] as parent
join dbo.split(@tparentid,',')
    on (parent.parentid = split.items)
```

I'm also using a `join` versus using `where ... in ( ... )` syntax as joins generally perform much faster.

Comment: @ pyrospade: Thank you for ur response but the code which u sent is not working .. The error thrown is Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure pr_tr_getlistofcompaniesss, Line 5 .The multi-part identifier "Companiesdata.parentid" could not be bound.

Comment: @ pyrospade: Thank you once again but if i execute the code for example consider pr_getlistofcompaniesss '1' then the output for your code is as follows: 
                                                                                     ID      Company name             Industry

222 apple Technologies software,software
223 xyz Technologies software,software
224     abc technologies        advertising,media

Instead i want the output as 


ID      Company name             Industry

222 apple Technologies software
223 xyz Technologies software
224     abc technologies        advertising,media

Comment: Just add the `distinct` keyword to the subquery (which has been updated in the answer).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but Thank you for ur answer .. i tried it and its partially correct,but the problem is if i have the same company name ( here abc technologies) with different parentid's then i am not  getting the desired result .. any help regarding this please ?

Comment: What is your "desired result"?  In your example, abc technologies has the same parent id in both rows, so it's hard to know what you are after.

Comment: Thankyou once again for your interest.If for example i have abc techonlogies with 2 ids (ex:4,6) then when i execute the store procedure pr_getlistofcompaniesss '4,6'then the output i am getting is                                                                  abc technologies advertising                                                                abc technologies media                                                                i.e i am getting in 2 rows but my desired output should be commaseparated if the company name is same.

Comment: Maybe you can try modifying the subquery where clause to `where child.parentid = parent.parentid or child.CompanyName = parent.CompanyName`.  However, you didn't mention that requirement, nor do your tables seem to be set up to do this (no id field for CompanyName), so this is more of a hack.

Comment: @pyrosade : Thank you for your time.Its just that an example i had given ... I didnt get what you are saying about the ID field for a companyname.Actually if i have two different ids for the same company then also it should get on the same row.. So i asked if u can help me out.Thank you once again but still my problem has not been solved.

Comment: Impossible for anyone to solve your issue if we don't have the appropriate information (e.g. your schema).  In fact, I think it can be debated that your original problem was solved a long time ago...proper etiquette would be to mark this response as the accepted answer and submit your new questions in a new post.