# SQL Server : Group by string concatenation

Tags: sql-server, group-by, concatenation, for-xml-path

I have a question. I know that has been asked before. I looked through the related questions but I could not get my SQL script to work.

Here is my query :

```
SELECT T1.PART_ID, T2.ID, T2.DESCRIPTION
FROM #TEMP T1 
INNER JOIN #TEMP2 T2 ON T1.PART_ID = T2.PART_ID
ORDER BY T2.ID
```

Table:

```
PART_ID |  ID        |    DESCRIPTION
----------------------------------
10002   |  1182505   |   Tagfahrlichtschaltung
80029   | 1182505    |   Bluetooth
20004   | 1212866    |    Kindersitzbefestigung
10045   |  1212866   |    Lederlenkradrriegelung
11908   |  1257946   |    Airbag
22346   | 1257946    |    Automatic
```

I want have the result like:

```
ID       | LISTOFPARTS
-----------------------------
1182505  |  "10002 : Tagfahrlichtschaltung ; 80029 : Bluetooth  "
1212866  |  "20004 : Kindersitzbefestigung ; 10045 : Lederlenkradrriegelung"
1257946  |  "11908 : AIRBAG ; 22346 : AUTOMATIC"
```

I guess it has to be something with XML PATH but I could not get it to work.
Could anyone rewrite the query so that it returns the results grouped and concatenated in string?

Solutions with or without XML PATH will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: suggestion: post up your schema in http://sqlfiddle.com/ to make it easier for us. *edit - this may be related to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405362/concatenate-multiple-rows-from-multiple-tables/10405475

Comment: 1st aren't you joining on the wrong field?  ID appears to be the same not part_ID.

Comment: No. Id is the VehicleID. PartID is the id of the part. PartID is common in CARS and CAR_PARTS tables. The description is taken from the CAR_PARTS table and joined to find the parts(descriptions) that a car has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work -

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (PART_ID INT,ID INT, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @TABLE 
VALUES
(10002   ,1182505   ,   'Tagfahrlichtschaltung')
,(80029   , 1182505    ,   'Bluetooth')
,(20004   , 1212866    ,    'Kindersitzbefestigung')
,(10045   ,  1212866   ,    'Lederlenkradrriegelung')
,(11908   ,  1257946   ,    'Airbag')
,(22346   , 1257946    ,    'Automatic')

;WITH SUBQUERY
AS
(
    SELECT ID,(CAST(PART_ID AS VARCHAR(12)) + ' : ' + DESCRIPTION) 'CONCATED'
    FROM @TABLE 
)

SELECT ID, LEFT(pre_trimmed.CONCATED , LEN(pre_trimmed.CONCATED )-1) AS LISTOFPARTS
FROM SUBQUERY AS extern
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT CONCATED + ','
    FROM SUBQUERY AS intern
    WHERE extern.ID = intern.ID
    FOR XML PATH('')
) pre_trimmed (CONCATED)
GROUP BY ID, pre_trimmed.CONCATED
```

Answer (score 2):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5441

```
create table #Temp (PART_ID bigint, ID bigint, DESCRIPTION nvarchar(max))

insert into #Temp
select 10002, 1182505, 'Tagfahrlichtschaltung' union all
select 80029, 1182505, 'Bluetooth' union all
select 20004, 1212866, 'Kindersitzbefestigung' union all
select 10045, 1212866, 'Lederlenkradrriegelung' union all
select 11908, 1257946, 'Airbag' union all
select 22346, 1257946, 'Automatic'

select 
    T1.ID,
    stuff(
        (
            select ' ; ' + cast(T2.PART_ID as nvarchar(max)) + ' : ' + T2.DESCRIPTION
            from #TEmp as T2
            where T2.ID = T1.ID 
            for xml path(''), type
        ).value('data(.)', 'nvarchar(max)')
    , 1, 3, '') as LISTOFPARTS
from #TEMP as T1 
group by T1.ID
order by T1.ID
```