# TSQL: Extract XML Nested Tags Into Columns

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

**Using SQLServer2008R2**

I currently have XML tags with data inside the XML tags (not between them), such as:

```
<zooid="1"><animals key="all" zebras="22" dogs="0" birds="4" /><animals key="all" workers="yes" vacation="occasion" /> ... *(more)*</zooid>
<zooid="2"><animals key="house" zebras="0" dogs="1" birds="2" /><animals key="house" workers="no" vacation="no" /> ... *(more)*</zoodid>
```

If I query the XML or use the value function against it, it returns blank values because it tries to read between tags - where no value exists.  I need it to read *inside* of the tags, parse out the values before the equal sign as columns and the values between the quotations as values inside those columns (granted, I could create a function that could do this, but this would be quite meticulous, and I'm curious if something like this already exists).  What it should look like this in **columns**:

```
Key | Zebras | Dogs | Birds | Key | Workers | Vacation | ... *(more)*
```

... and this in **rows of data**:

```
all   | 22 | 0 | 4 | all   | yes | occasion | ... *(more)*
house | 0  | 1 | 2 | house | no  | no       | ... *(more)*
```

So the final output (just using the two XML rows from the beginning for now), would look like the below data in table form:

```
Key   | Zebras | Dogs | Birds | Key    | Workers | Vacation | ... *(more)*
================================================================
all   | 22     | 0    | 4     | all   | yes     | occasion | ... *(more)*
house | 0      | 1    | 2     | house | no      | no       | ... *(more)*
```

Other than querying against XML, using the `.query` tool and even trying the `.node` tool (using `CROSS APPLY` see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115232/query-xml-field-with-t-sql)), I haven't been able to generate this.

Comment: You need one row for every `<animals ...>`  or one row for every `<zooid ...>` ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean One row for ever '<zooid ...>'

Comment: What if one `<zoo>` has one `<animals>` element and another `<zoo>` has two `<animals>` elements ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Most <zoo> elements have 18 <animals> elements.  For the exceptions (fewer than 5%, I could build a separate exception table).

Comment: What if a zoo has two `<animals>` elements with a `@Zebras` attribute ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean In that case, I'd have multiple Zebra columns.  Essentially, this is a "reference" table and when it's put together, code will extract the references column-by-column into an XML string (like it currently is).  This is solely for extracting these XML values into separate columns for references.  So in many cases, I'll have multiple Animal, Zebra, Workers columns per <zoo> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @YourXML NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @YourXML = '
    <zooid="1">
        <animals key="all" zebras="22" dogs="0" birds="4" />
        <animals key="all" workers="yes" vacation="occasion" />
    </zooid>
    <zooid="2">
        <animals key="house" zebras="0" dogs="1" birds="2" />
        <animals key="house" workers="no" vacation="no" />
    </zoodid>'

DECLARE @XML XML
SELECT @XML = 
    REPLACE(
          REPLACE(@YourXML, 'zooid=', 'zooid id=')
        , '</zoodid>'
        , '</zooid>')

SELECT 
      d.[Key]
    , Dogs = MAX(d.Dogs)
    , Zebras = MAX(d.Zebras)
    , Birds = MAX(d.Birds)
    , Workers = MAX(d.Workers)
    , Vacation = MAX(d.Vacation)
FROM (
    SELECT 
          [Key] = t.p.value('./@key', 'NVARCHAR(50)')
        , Zebras = t.p.value('./@zebras', 'INT')
        , Dogs = t.p.value('./@dogs', 'INT')
        , Birds = t.p.value('./@birds', 'INT')
        , Workers = t.p.value('./@workers', 'NVARCHAR(20)')
        , Vacation = t.p.value('./@vacation', 'NVARCHAR(20)')
    FROM @XML.nodes('/zooid/animals') t(p)
) d
GROUP BY d.[Key]
```

Comment: is *t(p)* at the end of the FROM in the SUB-SELECT an alias, or does is that referring back to something in the XML?

Comment: <xml>.nodes(<xml-path>) AS <alias>(<rowset-from-xml-path>)

Answer (score 1):

Your xml appears invalid.  How are you able to specify an element like this: ?  Generally xml structure is <(elementName) (Attribute)="(Value)"/>.  Unless I am mistaken if you are casting text to xml the way it is it will fail.  Saying that I can show a working example for proper xml in a self extracting example that will run in SQL Managment Studio as is.

```
declare @text1 varchar(max) = '<zooid="1"><animals="all" zebras="22" dogs="0" birds="4" /><animals="all" workers="yes" vacation="occasion" /></zooid>'
,   @text2 varchar(max) = '<a zooid="1"><b animals="all" zebras="22" dogs="0" birds="4" /><b animals="all" workers="yes" vacation="occasion" /></a>'
,   @xml xml
;

begin try 
    set @xml = cast(@text1 as xml)
end try
begin catch
    set @xml = '<ElementName Attribute="BadData Elements are not named" />'
end catch 

select @xml

begin try 
    set @xml = cast(@text2 as xml)
end try
begin catch
    set @xml = '<ElementName Attribute="BadData" />'
end catch 

select  
    @xml.value('(/a/b/@animals)[1]', 'varchar(20)') as AnimalsValue
,   @xml.value('(/a/b/@zebras)[1]', 'int') as ZebrasValue
,   @xml.value('(/a/b/@dogs)[1]', 'int') as DogsValue
,   @xml.value('(/a/b/@birds)[1]', 'int') as BirdsValue
,   @xml.value('(/a/b/@workers)[1]', 'varchar(16)') as Workers
,   @xml.value('(/a/b/@vacation)[1]', 'varchar(16)') as Vacation
```

The '.value' method is a syntax for querying xml in SQL.  I am basically finding the elements(I did generics of a that contained b).  Then once at the level I want '@animals' stands for 'attribute of name animals'.  The [1] is a position since I can only return one thing at a time, so I chose the first position.  Then it needs to a datatype to return.  Text is varchar and numbers are ints.

XML query methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx

Comment: Thanks; I was missing the name "key" after animals; you're right - the syntax was wrong.

Comment: No problem, xml is a whole other beast to SQL Server.  I worked with it enough to see text to xml changes when they appear incorrect.