# SQL Server - Update a column with other column values as CSV

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

**Script for table and sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLE1(ID INT, COL1 NVARCHAR(10))
CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLE2(ID INT, COL2 NVARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE1 (ID) VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE1 (ID) VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE1 (ID) VALUES(3)

INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE2 (ID,COL2) VALUES(1,'A')
INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE2 (ID,COL2) VALUES(1,'B')
INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE2 (ID,COL2) VALUES(1,'C')
INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE2 (ID,COL2) VALUES(2,'X')
INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE2 (ID,COL2) VALUES(2,'Y')
INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE2 (ID,COL2) VALUES(3,'Z')
```

I need to update the `#TEMPTABLE1` so that

```
ID COL1
---------
1  A,B,C 
2  X,Y
3  Z
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return multiple values in one column (T-SQL)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122942/how-to-return-multiple-values-in-one-column-t-sql)

Comment: **DO NOT STORE CSV DATA IN COLUMS! EVER!**

Comment: Joel, I'm not storing the CSV data in the column. This is a part of reporting and I came across this problem and posted here.

Comment: If you're not storing the CSV data in a column, then why do you need an UPDATE statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounded like OP wanted an update statement.

```
UPDATE [x]
SET
    [COL1] = STUFF
            (
                (
                    SELECT
                        N',' + [COL2]
                    FROM
                        [#TEMPTABLE2] AS [y]
                    WHERE
                        [y].[ID] = [x].[ID]
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                ).value(N'.', N'nvarchar(10)'), 
                1, 1, N''
            )
OUTPUT INSERTED.*
FROM
    [#TEMPTABLE1] AS [x]
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems the key to your question is concatenating the values in #temptable2 based on the id.  Jeff Moden has an excellent article on this at [Concatenation Functions and Some Tuning Myths](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Test+Data/61572/)

While the entire article is well worth reading, the key thingis that you can easily use Stuff and For XML Path with a subquery to concatenate based on the ID column.  Then you can readily use that to update your #temptable1.

**Edit to add example**

The concatenation would look roughly like:

```
SELECT t1.ID,        
STUFF((SELECT ','+t2.value
   FROM dbo.TestData t2 
   WHERE t1.ID = t2.SomeID FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')   
FROM dbo.TestData t1  
GROUP BY t1.ID
```

Comment: Need to be aware of character entitization when using the FOR XML method.  

Add INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE2 (ID,COL2) VALUES(3,N'<') and see if the "<" symbol is properly represented.

Change to ().value('.', 'nvarchar(10)') to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 1):

First create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CommaValues(@ID as INT)
returns varchar(500)
as
begin
DECLARE @DelimList as varchar(500)

select @DelimList = COALESCE(@DelimList + ', ', '') + Col2
from #TEMPTABLE2
where ID = @ID

return @DelimList
end
```

and then use it in your update:

```
UPDATE #TEMPTABLE1 set Col1 = CommaValues(ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work:

```
INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE1 SELECT ID,COL2 FROM #TEMPTABLE2 GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to be able to issue multiple inserts in order to update a column (hence separate `insert` and `update` statements).  I see two options:

**Insert Then Update**

```
INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE2 (ID,COL2) VALUES(1,'A')
UPDATE #TEMPTABLE2 SET COL2 = COL2 + ',' + B WHERE ID = 1
UPDATE #TEMPTABLE2 SET COL2 = COL2 + ',' + C WHERE ID = 1
```

This is fairly messy, but works.

**Insert, but Select into a comma-delimited list**
In this case, you can make your primary key the combination of ID and COL2 (although I'm not sure I would recommend this) and insert the values as you are doing so above.  Then, when you need the comma-delimited list, select it as such, for example, using collate (as mentioned by [Pinal Dave](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/04/sql-server-create-a-comma-delimited-list-using-select-clause-from-table-column/)):

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + Name
FROM Production.Product
```