# How to get result of LEFT join into another table as one field

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, left-join

Not sure how to describe this so I will show example:

table **PAGES**

```
id      int
parent  int
name    nvarchar
status  tinyint
```

table **PAGES_MODULES**

```
id          int 
id_parent   int
module_type nvarchar
module_id   int
status      int
```

One page can have more than one linked modules. Example records:

```
id    parent    name     status
1     -1        Xyz      1
2     -1        Yqw      1

id    id_parent    module_type    module_id     status
1     1            ARTICLE        1             1
2     1            GALLERY        2             1
3     2            CATEGORY       3             1
```

What I need is to create select which will not return 2 results if I do select left join page_modules.

I would like to have select which returns linked modules as this:

```
id    parent    name     status    modules
1     -1        Xyz      1         ARTICLE GALLERY
2     -1        Yqw      1         CATEGORY
```

Is that possible?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I have tried COALESE, CROSS APPLY and SELECT within SELECT methods and came to these conclusions:

http://blog.feronovak.com/2011/10/multiple-values-in-one-column-aka.html

Hope I can publish these here, not meaning to spam or something.

Comment: id_parent in PAGES_MODULES is a foreign key to PAGES.id?

Comment: Try using the `coalesce` function, as mentioned in [this SO question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122942/how-to-return-multiple-values-in-one-column-t-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to create a custom aggregate function that could concatenate the strings together, there is no built-in SQL Server function that does this.

You can create a custom aggregate function (assuming your using the latest version of SQL) using a .Net assembly.  Here's the MS reference on how to do this (the example in the article is actually for a CONCATENATE function just like you require): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182741.aspx

Comment: pretty tricky stuffy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 1):

Use [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to smoosh multiple rows' worth of data into a single field like that. Note that it does have a length limit (1024 chars by default), so if you're going to have a zillion records being group_concatted, you'll only get the first few lines worth unless you raise the limit.

```
SELECT ..., GROUP_CONCAT(modules SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM ...
GROUP BY ...
```

Note that it IS an aggregate function, so you must have a group-by clause.

Comment: i think thats MySQL only, don't think MSSQL has an equiv aggregate function.

Comment: AH. Doh, right. I did find some workarounds for it somewhere at one point. here's one on so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 1):

```
-- ==================
-- sample data
-- ==================
declare @pages table
(
    id int,
    parent int,
    name nvarchar(max),
    status tinyint
)

declare @pages_modules table
(
    id int,
    id_parent int,
    module_type nvarchar(max),
    module_id int,
    status int
)

insert into @pages values (1, -1, 'Xyz', 1)
insert into @pages values (2, -1, 'Yqw', 1)

insert into @pages_modules values (1, 1, 'ARTICLE', 1, 1)
insert into @pages_modules values (2, 1, 'GALLERY', 2, 1)
insert into @pages_modules values (3, 2, 'CATEGORY', 3, 1)


-- ==================
-- solution
-- ==================
select 
    *,
    modules = (
        select module_type + ' ' from @pages_modules pm
        where pm.id_parent = p.id
        for xml path('')
    )
from @pages p
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join both tables and then `GROUP BY` by *pages.id*, *pages.parent*, *pages.status*, *pages.name* and *pages.status*. Your *modules* field in your resultset is then a string aggregate function, i.e in Oracle `LISTAGG(pages_modules.modules, ' ') as modules`.