# SQL Query to Concatenate one column and have a bunch of other columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Concatenate row values T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874966/concatenate-row-values-t-sql)

I have a table like this:

```
ref_num   name      type       route
----------------------------------------
1         A         W          401
2         B         X          401
3         C         E          401
3         C         E          411
4         D         Z          401
5         K         W          701
5         K         W          991
5         K         W          556
5         K         W          401
6         L         X          401
7         D         Y          401
7         D         Y          411
7         D         Y          680
8         E         Z          401
```

And i want a RESULT like this:

```
ref_num   name      type       routes
----------------------------------------
1         A         W          401
2         B         X          401
3         C         E          401,411
4         D         Z          401
5         K         W          701,991,556,401
6         L         X          401
7         D         Y          401,411,680
8         E         Z          401
```

If anybody can give me a query example to get the desired result it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122942/how-to-return-multiple-values-in-one-column-t-sql, or This: http://ray.jez.net/concatenation-with-coalesce/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select ref_num, name, type, group_concat(routes)
from your_table
group by ref_num
```

In MySQL you don't have to  `group by` all values you are selecting. Other values will probably selected by random. But if the other values are the same in one group then you don't have to worry. That is the case in the OP's question.

Comment: dont you need to group by  name and type?

Comment: In the OP's example these values are always the same.

Comment: @Diego: Yes and no. If all the table's rows are as the example - `name` and `type` depend on `ref_num`, no you don't have to. In MySQL and with the proper settings.

Comment: yeah but it would be good to add it in case there are different ones. I didn't down voted you btw

Comment: Still, GROUP BY will require NAME and TYPE for this query.

Comment: @juergend: It would be good to explain when you have and when you don't have to. Or why you chose this one.

Comment: @PaddyC: Not in MySQL (it isn't required as in other DBMS). But it may let the query show random results - in some cases.

Comment: See this [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d17ab/1)

Comment: This behaviour (default in MySQL) can be disabled by setting sql_mode to [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

Comment: @ypercube Ah, understood, thanks for clarification, my comment is Oracle specific.

Answer (score 3):

You can Concatenate them with [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) with `GROUP BY`, something like:

```
SELECT ref_num, name, type, GROUP_CONCAT(routes SEPARATOR ', ')   
FROM TableNAme 
GROUP BY ref_num, name, type
```

Answer (score 0):

I think WM_CONCAT will do this:

```
SELECT REF_NUM, NAME, TYPE, WM_CONCAT(ROUTE) 
FROM ROUTES
GROUP BY REF_NUM, NAME, TYPE;
```

Comment: Ah, apologies, WM_CONCAT is Oracle-specific. My bad :) Learn something every day...