# SQL select -one to many joins want to have the manys

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables, TBL_PARENT (parentID, ParentName) and TBL_CHILDREN (ParentID,Child_Name) 
A Parent can have 0 to many children

What I want is a query to give me a list of parent and their children in single row per parent.

For example

```
Parent1 John,Mary

Parent2 jane,steve,jana
```

And the number of rows to be the total number of parents

Comment: Is this a candidate for a "Right Outer Join"?

Comment: I tried with left join and it is giving duplicates. Like if I do SELECT P.PARENTID, C.NAME FROM TBL_PARENT P LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_CHILDREN C

Comment: Asked and answered many times on this forum. Do a search for "sql stuff xml"  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+stuff+xml

Comment: Declan_K couldn't find similar

Comment: Here is the answer you need. It was not the accepted answer to the question, but it is the right answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/177153/2324286

Comment: I would tend to agree here.

Comment: I can't use a T-SQL, it has to be a straight query

Comment: Then just use the `SELECT` portion of the attached as a template. It does not need to be wrapped in procedural code to utilize the `STUFF...XML` construct.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(P.parentID),
P.ParentName, 
C.Child_Name 
FROM TBL_PARENT as P
INNER JOIN TBL_CHILDREN as C  
WHERE P.parentID == c.ParentID
GROUP BY P.ParentName;
```

The line **P.parentID == c.ParentID** is doing the Join, and the line **count(P.parentID)** is doing the count of all the parents and the line **GROUP BY P.ParentName** is grouping all the rows by the name of the parent so you can display all the children of every single parent.

Answer (score 0):

try this query :
I have created 3 table 2 of them are already created on your database #parant, #ch
and the third one is a temp table to put the result in.

```
create table #parant (id int , name varchar(10))
create table #ch (id int , name varchar(10), pid int)

insert into #parant select 1,'PA'
insert into #parant select 2,'PB'
insert into #parant select 3,'PC'

insert into #ch select 1,'Ca',1
insert into #ch select 1,'Cb',1
insert into #ch select 1,'Cc',1
insert into #ch select 1,'Cd',3
insert into #ch select 1,'Cf',3
insert into #ch select 1,'Ch',1




create table #testTable (id int, name varchar(10),chid int, chname varchar(10), cpid int)

insert into #testTable 
select x.id , x.name ,isnull( y.id ,0), isnull(y.name,'') ,isnull(y.pid ,0)
from #parant as x
left outer join #ch as y
on x .id = y .pid 

SELECT t.ID, t.name , STUFF(
(SELECT ',' + s.chname
FROM #TestTable s
WHERE s.ID = t.ID
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS CSV
FROM #TestTable AS t
GROUP BY t.ID, t.name
GO


drop table #testTable 
drop table #ch 
drop table #parant
```

for the above data i got the following result

1   PA  Ca,Cb,Cc,Ch
2   PB
3   PC  Cd,Cf

Comment: wala rawashdeh, thanks for the answer and it works perfect. Next question is if I have a third table, FRIEND and want to display friends of the parent ( a parent can have 0 to many friends) in the same result set, how do I modify the syntax ? Thanks