# how to convert varchar columns to comma separated row values

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
id Name
1  A
2  C
2  D
1  B
```

Output required through `T-sql`

```
id Name
1  A,B
2  C,D
```

Comment: Please edit! Format your data, to rows with columns!

Comment: I think this is a duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122942/how-to-return-multiple-values-in-one-column-t-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
;
WITH    SampleData
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     ( VALUES ( 1, 'A'), ( 2, 'C'), ( 2, 'D'), ( 1, 'B'),
                        ( 1, 'C' ) ) T ( id, name )
             )
    SELECT  DISTINCT
            B.Id ,
            SUBSTRING(( SELECT  ',' + Name
                        FROM    SampleData AS A
                        WHERE   A.Id = B.ID
                      FOR
                        XML PATH('')
                      ), 2, 1000) AS NAME
    FROM    SampleData AS B
```

output result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
SELECT   test.id,  test.Name+','+ Table1_1.Name AS Name
FROM         (SELECT     MIN(Name) AS Name, id
                       FROM          Table1
                       GROUP BY id) AS test RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      Table1 AS Table1_1 ON test.id = Table1_1.id
                        where test.Name <>Table1_1.Name
```

Comment: this will not work when id will be replicated more than two times

Comment: Are you saying if there was another row of 1,A or something like 1,E? if my values look something like below, it would still show just the two distinct values: VALUES
 (1, 'A'),
 (2, 'C'),
 (2, 'D'),
 (1, 'B'),
 (1, 'A'),
 (1, 'A'),
 (2, 'C')

Comment: try with VALUES (1, 'A'), (1, 'B'), (1, 'C'), (1, 'D')  and you will see what I'm talking about

Comment: ok, that makes sense. I was looking it as creating pairs of data (A,B), (C,D), (A,E) ,etc, not combining all Names into one row grouped by the ID.

Comment: your solution works well for pairs, but "what if" also need to be taking into consideration