# How to pivot dynamic number of columns row result into a verticle result list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There is a single row of data in a table that will have a varying number of columns named C1, C2, C3.. etc.  I can locate that row but i want to un-pivot those dynamic number of columns values into a single column result...  I have researched a ton on pivot/unpivot stuff but all examples i've found don't seem to handle the dynamic number of columns in the results.

Native Results:

### Col 1   Col 2   Col 3   Col 4   Col 5.... Col X

Id  Name    DOB City    State

Desired Results:

### ColumnNameTBD:

Id
Name
DOB
City
State

Thank You!

Tim

Comment: I think you may need dynamic SQL to handle the case where you don't know the names of the columns beforehand. See, for instance, the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985796/pivot-dynamic-columns-no-aggregation).

Comment: That is because a dynamic number of columns violates everything about relational tables. I am guessing this "table" is the result of a dynamic pivot? What is not at all clear is what you are really trying to do. You listed 5 example columns with the same 5 columns in your output. Try to explain more clearly what is going on and we can find a way to help.

Comment: Yes to Joe and Sean: @TimWiley, you'll probably need dynamic SQL (not necessarily a problem) and can you provide a more detailed example of what you want, including data.

Comment: We get a mangled excel spreadsheet and structured data doesn't begin until somewhere in the sheet that changes...There are 4 columns that are always there... the rest are variable(1 to 100)....  So i import the excel spreadsheet raw into a SQL Server table and then i can locate the record descriptor row and anything below that is the structured data...  We don't have control of the export format and i don't want to macro this in excel to clean it up as i want it fully automated...    i just about have it working with Cross Apply, XML Path and dynamic sql as suggested.

Comment: Guys forgive me on Stack Etiquette as i wish i could give all of you the credit on the answer...

Answer (score 0):

After feedback from to the question i was able to piece together the solution.  I now have a way to physically instanciate structure from dynamic/inconsistent structure automatically.

```
    DECLARE @sColumnNames As Varchar(5000)
    DECLARE @sSQL  AS  Varchar(5000);

    --Flatten List of Column Names
     Select @sColumnNames = ' ' + (
                 Select '(' + COLUMN_NAME + '),' As 'data()'
                  From  SMAR_STG.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  With (NoLock) 
                 where TABLE_NAME = 'V_ETL_CTX_COREM_EXCEL_DTL_COLUMNS'
                   For XML PATH('')
            )  + ' '

    --Get Rid or trailing Comma
    Set @sColumnNames = substring(@Output,1,len(@Output) -1) 

    -- Assemble SQL Statement
    Set @sSQL = 'SELECT Upivot AS X
                FROM   SMAR_STG.DBO.V_ETL_CTX_COREM_EXCEL_DTL_COLUMNS
                       CROSS apply (VALUES '
    Set @sSql = @sSQL + @sColumnNames
    Set @sSQL = @sSQL + ') cs (upivot) '

    -- Execute
    EXEC (@sSql)
```

Answer (score -2):

This item was already [resolved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122942/how-to-return-multiple-values-in-one-column-t-sql)

As you will see from the article from the link, you will need to use COALESCE function to achive this