# How do I get the right 2 dimensional array for this table in H2?

Tags: sql, h2

This is my H2 table.

| Step 1 | time |
| Step 2 | time |
| Step 3 | time |
| Step 4 | time |
| Step 5 | time |
| Step 1 | time |
| Step 2 | time |
| Step 3 | time |
| Step 4 | time |
| Step 5 | time |

I need to write a SQL query that fetches the result like so:

| Step 1 | time | time |
| Step 2 | time | time |
| Step 3 | time | time |
| Step 4 | time | time |
| Step 5 | time | time |

How do I fetch it this way? Is this possible?

Comment: Do you have only two values for each step or can you have more?

Comment: These are test results. So if there are ten steps and the test was executed 5 times, then I would have Step 1 through 10 five times along with the time taken for each of those steps

Comment: This is a specific instance of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102317/how-to-get-multiple-records-against-one-record-based-on-relation/106334)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have more than two values for each step, you could do

```
SELECT step_col, GROUP_CONCAT(time_col)
FROM H2 GROUP BY step_col
```

Then you can easily split `time_col` values in your code.
Check [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) syntax to understand how you can use it the way you please.