# how to show multiple names in one column ireport 4.5 in java

Tags: java, ireport

stackoverflow forum member I am having some problem with a certain report designed using ireport 4.5 I am able to group the data. Now I want that the employee name should be come in one line only ex: Hiren,Yogesh,Jayesh,Aakash,Niraj etc.

**But with my design the employee names comes in new row.**

I **want the employee name should come in one row only with separated by "," like Hiren,Yogesh,Jayesh,Aakash,Niraj**

[image: employee report]

**is there any way to do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your source is a SQL database, then do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102317/how-to-get-multiple-records-against-one-record-based-on-relation).

If your source is something else, then create a variable to concatenate the string values. Don't use the detail band. Put the variable into the group footer (or header) as the Employee.