# How to avoid redundant attributes in sql?

Tags: sql

I currently have this table.

```
name               title
Robert Pattinson   Twilight
Daniel Radcliff    NULL
Leonardo Dicaprio  NULL
Charlie Chaplin    The kid
Charlie Chaplin    The Circus
Charlie Chaplin    Timelight
John Abraham       Dhoom
John Abraham       Race 2
```

Is there a way to avoid duplicate attributes like 'Charlie Chaplin' and get a result as follows?

```
name               title

Robert Pattinson   Twilight
Daniel Radcliff    NULL
Leonardo Dicaprio  NULL
Charlie Chaplin    The kid, The Circus,Timelight
John Abraham       Dhoom,Race 2
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: You may want to check following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102317/how-to-get-multiple-records-against-one-record-based-on-relation

Comment: Thnx a lot. It worked.