# How can i merge duplicate rows in SQL with an special condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, rows, no-duplicates

i have a table with this structure

```
ID    Word         description
-------------------------------
1     book       a lot of paper
2     book       a thing
3     book       an amazing thing
4     tv         television
```

i want to convert this table to:

```
ID    Word         description
-------------------------------
1     book       a lot of paper,a thing,an amazing thing
2     tv         television
```

Note that :

-The maximum number of duplication is six

-I want to have a table without duplicate rows , i want to merge all duplicate rows to one row with all description values.

Thanks for your helps...

Comment: sorry, I will update with an answer, that wasn't what you were actually looking for

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server aggregate string concatenation".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS Id,
    *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Word,
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + description
               FROM Your_Table
               WHERE Word = T.Word
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS description
    FROM Your_Table T) AS A
```

Comment: Too much information! You can search with word key: STUFF, XML PATH :)

Comment: Thanks for your Great help ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your query u should group by word and concatenate by description

Tested this on mysql, not sure if it will work on sql server

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(description SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM tablename GROUP BY word
```

and for mssql server
try the answer provided by @mdahlman

https://stackoverflow.com/a/106334/3664960