# Concatenate multiple rows in an array with SQL on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table constructed like this :

```
oid | identifier | value
1   | 10         | 101
2   | 10         | 102
3   | 20         | 201
4   | 20         | 202
5   | 20         | 203
```

I'd like to query this table to get a result like this :

```
identifier | values[]
10         | {101, 102}
20         | {201, 202, 203}
```

I can't figure a way to do that.
Is that possible? How?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query

Answer (score 109, accepted):

This is a Postgres built-in since a few versions so you no longer need to define your own, the name is `array_agg()`.

```
test=> select array_agg(n) from generate_series(1,10) n group by n%2;
  array_agg   
--------------
 {1,3,5,7,9}
 {2,4,6,8,10}
```

(this is Postgres 8.4.8).

Note that no `ORDER BY` is specified, so the order of the result rows depends on the grouping method used (here, hash) ie, it is not defined. Example:

```
test=> select n%2, array_agg(n) from generate_series(1,10) n group by (n%2);
 ?column? |  array_agg   
----------+--------------
        1 | {1,3,5,7,9}
        0 | {2,4,6,8,10}

test=> select (n%2)::TEXT, array_agg(n) from generate_series(1,10) n group by (n%2)::TEXT;
 text |  array_agg   
------+--------------
 0    | {2,4,6,8,10}
 1    | {1,3,5,7,9}
```

Now, I don't know why you get `{10,2,4,6,8}` and `{9,7,3,1,5}`, since `generate_series()` should send the rows in order.

Comment: In PostgreSQL 8.4.8 this returns: {10,2,4,6,8} and {9,7,3,1,5}. I think the above output is from version 9.

Comment: I don't know either why the rows/elements are returned in the order which I see them. I just copied the code and pasted it in to see what it did.

Comment: You can choose the order of the elements in the array - see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a2c9f608771055910d958403d60df7b3)! Why the default is the way it is is a mystery...

Answer (score 18):

Simple example: each course have many lessons, so if i run code below:

```
SELECT
  lessons.course_id AS course_id,
  array_agg(lessons.id) AS lesson_ids
FROM lessons
GROUP BY
  lessons.course_id
ORDER BY
  lessons.course_id
```

i'd get next result:

```
┌───────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ course_id │                   lesson_ids                         │
├───────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│         1 │ {139,140,141,137,138,143,145,174,175,176,177,147,... │
│         3 │ {32,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,... │
│         5 │ {663,664,665,649,650,651,652,653,654,655,656,657,... │
│         7 │ {985,984,1097,974,893,971,955,960,983,1045,891,97... │
│       ...                                                        │
└───────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: This is *almost* perfect.  The problem is that the lessons.id values are unsorted.

Answer (score 17):

You have to create an aggregate function, e.g.

```
CREATE AGGREGATE array_accum (anyelement)
(
sfunc = array_append,
stype = anyarray,
initcond = '{}'
);
```

then

```
SELECT identifier, array_accum(value) AS values FROM table GROUP BY identifier;
```

HTH

Comment: I get the following error when trying to create this aggregate function: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("

Comment: Are you using PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code for the requested output.

```
select identifier, array_agg(value)
from (
  values
    (1   , 10         , 101),
    (2   , 10         , 102),
    (3   , 20         , 201),
    (4   , 20         , 202),
    (5   , 20         , 203)
  ) as tab (oid, identifier, value)
group by identifier
order by identifier;
```