# Merge non-adjacent polygons in Qgis or Postgres

Tags: postgresql, merge, postgis, qgis

I am working with Qgis and PostgreSQL. But i can't figure out how to merge the  non-adjacent polygons in my screenshot into one record? Can anybody help mee with this problem?

I want all the polygons with the same cat to be merged in one record.

**See screenshot here:**

[image]

Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want use Postgres you need create a `SELECT` using [**ST_Union**](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html)

```
geometry ST_Union(geometry set g1field);

geometry ST_Union(geometry g1, geometry g2);

geometry ST_Union(geometry[] g1_array);
```

You can try this to create one array

[Concatenate multiple rows in an array with SQL on PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533256/concatenate-multiple-rows-in-an-array-with-sql-on-postgresql)

I try this one in my states tables and work ok

```
SELECT ST_Union(a_geom)
FROM  (SELECT  array_agg(e.geom) as a_geom 
       FROM mapas.estadosven_region e
      ) t
```

I make another test and looks like this also may work

```
SELECT ID, ST_Union(geom) 
FROM test_dissolve_function t 
WHERE ST_isValid(geom)='t' 
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: Thnx for replying Juan! I looked it up and i have this so far but how can you show the cat column?                                                              

SELECT geom, ST_multi(ST_Union(f.geom))
FROM test_dissolve_function As f
GROUP BY geom

Comment: What code did you run? Because i get this ERROR:  GEOSUnaryUnion: TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point after running this code:SELECT cat, ST_multi(ST_Union(f.geom))
FROM test_dissolve_function As f
GROUP BY cat

Comment: I get this ERROR:  GEOSUnaryUnion: TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point 234754.01867566622 579837.20636547857 at 234754.01867566622 579837.20636547857

Comment: Looks like is something with  your data. In my case im sure states borders arent exact so some intersection also occurs. Can you try join only two simple objects first? instead of all the table? use the first signature of `ST_Union` Also you can encampsule the function to something like join_mygeom(id) so you find what join is giving you error. Make the function return -1 if any error

Comment: i ran SELECT ST_IsValid(geom) FROM test_dissolve_function; and i got 1 rows that returned falls so i think it's my data but i don't know how to solve that yet

Comment: Well try with ST_IsValidDetail. But that should be a different question. http://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValidDetail.html

Comment: Yeah you're right that is a different question. But they are self intersecting. But i will check how to solve that. Thnx a lot for all your help!

Comment: try again the `ST_Union` function with `where id not in (not valid_ids) `

Comment: doesn't recognize the valid_ids. But can't i just use  ST_MakeValid? Or will that screw up my data?

Comment: dont do that unless you back your data first. Or create a new table. But again you can do `ST_UNION  ..... Where ST_isValid(geom)`

Comment: Now my query looks like this SELECT ST_Union(geom) FROM (SELECT array_agg(test_dissolve_function.geom) as geom FROM test_dissolve_function WHERE ST_isValid(geom)='t' )t; But it only returns one row. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `SELECT ID, ST_Union(geom) FROM ( SELECT ID, array_agg(t.geom) as geom FROM test_dissolve_function  t WHERE ST_isValid(geom)='t'  group by ID) t;`

Comment: Please check my edit. Looks like you can use the `ST_Union()` as a `SUM()` or `COUNT()` let me know if work for you.

Comment: Hey Juan, both codes work! thnx a lot! The code is a lot cleaner when you use ST_Union() like you would with SUM() or COUNT().