# String Aggregation in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, string-aggregation

Anyone knows if String Aggregation in sqlite is possible? 
If i have an animal column with 5 rows/datas, how can i combine them so that the output would be in one field
'dog','cat','rat','mice','mouse' as animals

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You're looking for something like the following:

```
select group_concat(animal) from animals;
```

This will return something like the following:

```
dog,cat,rat,mice,mouse
```

If you don't want to use a comma as the separator, you can add your own separator as a second parameter:

```
select group_concat(animal, '_') from animals;
```

which will return:

```
dog_cat_rat_mice_mouse
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will be useful:

```
group_concat(X)
group_concat(X,Y)
```

***The group_concat() function returns a string which is the concatenation of all non-NULL values of X. If parameter Y is present then it is used as the separator between instances of X. A comma (",") is used as the separator if Y is omitted. The order of the concatenated elements is arbitrary.***

Comment: Question asking about order: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897352/sqlite-group-concat-ordering