# Merge two rows in sql join statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

My join query looks like this:

```
select distinct A.id as plan_id, A.start_date, A.end_date, C.title 
from cp_plan A left outer join cp_plan_zone_map B 
on A.id = B.plan_id left outer join cp_zone C 
on B.zone_id = C.id where A.status = 'in-planning'
```

This gives me the following result:

[image]

Since my plan id, start date and end date are all same, all I want is to merge the title like this:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you try `pivot` ?
[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: Nice description here aswell. However, I find easier to implement GROUP_CONCAT() func but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate over the `plan_id`, `start_date`, and `end_date`, and use `GROUP_CONCAT` to generate the hyphen separated list of titles:

```
SELECT
    A.id AS plan_id,
    A.start_date,
    A.end_date,
    GROUP_CONCAT(C.title, '-') AS title
FROM cp_plan A
LEFT JOIN cp_plan_zone_map B 
    ON A.id = B.plan_id
LEFT JOIN cp_zone C 
    ON B.zone_id = C.id
WHERE
    A.status = 'in-planning'
GROUP BY
    A.id,
    A.start_date,
    A.end_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3515329/2253883):

```
SELECT A.id AS plan_id,
       A.start_date,
       A.end_date,
       group_concat(C.title, '-') AS title
FROM cp_plan A
LEFT OUTER JOIN cp_plan_zone_map B ON A.id = B.plan_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN cp_zone C ON B.zone_id = C.id
WHERE A.status = 'in-planning'
GROUP BY plan_id
```