# Join SQL output of a N-M relationship table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a relational database which schema is:

```
Book (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT)
Author (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)
BookAuthor (book_id INTEGER, author_id INTEGER)
```

*Note: obvious FOREIGN KEY constraints exist in the `BookAuthor` table, but I omitted them above just to save some space*

BookAuthor is a table that associates a book with one author.

Now, if I want to print out a book and its authors I can use:

```
SELECT book.title, author.name 
FROM book 
LEFT JOIN BookAuthor ON Book.id = BookAuthor.book_id 
LEFT JOIN author ON author.id = BookAuthor.id
```

(The `LEFT JOIN` is necessary if I want to list also the books that have no authors available in the database).

The output is

```
Book1|Author1
Book1|Author2
Book1|Author3
Book2|Author4
Book2|Author2
Book3|Author5
...
```

I was wondering if there is a way to join all titles in a single row, printing something like

```
Book1|Author1, Author2, Author3
Book2|Author4, Author2
Book3|Author5
```

using only SQL (of course I can postprocess the data, I was just curious if it was possible)?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: The suggested answer was a bit off, since I'm using sqlite, but this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515267/string-aggregation-in-sqlite helped me. Thanks