# Using ORDER BY clause inside GROUP_CONCAT function in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-concat

I don't think that I can use `ORDER BY` clause  inside the `GROUP_CONCAT` function.

Does anyone know a tricky way to accomplish this behavior in `SQLite`?

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897352/sqlite-group-concat-ordering) before. But I have a complex query .

My statement looks like this:

```
SELECT
    c.col1, c.col3, m.col3, m.col4,
    count(m.col1), count(re.col2) AS cnt,
    GROUP_CONCAT(p.col1 ORDER BY p.col1) AS "Group1",
    GROUP_CONCAT(p.col2 ORDER BY p.col1) AS "Group2", 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN con.col3 is null THEN p.col1 ELSE con.col3 END),
    con.col4, con.col5, p.col3
FROM t1 re
    INNER JOIN t2  c  ON (re.col1  = c.col1)
    INNER JOIN t3  p  ON (re.col2  = p.col1)
    LEFT JOIN  t4 con ON (con.col1 = p.col2)
    INNER JOIN  t5 m  ON (m.col1   = c.col5) 
GROUP BY re.col1
```

`Group1` and `Group2` is coming from the same table but different columns: I want to preserve the order of the `Group1` with `Group2`:

```
table t3 
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|    1 | A    |
|    2 | B    |
|    3 | C    |
|    4 | D    |
|    5 | E    |
+------+------+
```

so if `Group1` appears like this `2,1,3` `Group2` should appear like this `B,A,C`

Comment: You write in your answer that the query does what you need. What is the question then?

Comment: @newtover the syntax he used is supported by mysql not sqlite.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sqlite group\_concat ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897352/sqlite-group-concat-ordering)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I have tried this and it make the work

```
SELECT
    c.col1, c.col3, m.col3, m.col4,
    count(m.col1), count(re.col2) AS cnt,
    GROUP_CONCAT(p.col1 ORDER BY p.col1) AS "Group1",
    GROUP_CONCAT(p.col2 ORDER BY p.col1) AS "Group2", 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN con.col3 is null THEN p.col1 ELSE con.col3 END),
    con.col4, con.col5, p.col3
FROM t1 re
    INNER JOIN t2 c   ON (re.col1  = c.col1)
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM t3 ORDER BY col1
    ) AS          p   ON (re.col2  = p.col1)
    LEFT JOIN  t4 con ON (con.col1 = p.col2)
    INNER JOIN t5 m   ON (m.col1   = c.col5) 
GROUP BY re.col1
```

Comment: Is the `GROUP_CONCAT(column ORDER BY some_column)` syntax really supported by SQLite? For me it fails at `ORDER` (SQLite 3.4.7)

Comment: This does not work in sqlite. It fails at ORDER like zapl said above

Comment: @confucius I think the key here is that you rewrote `t3` as ordered, but **forgot to remove the `ORDER BY p.col1` from the `GROUP_CONCAT`s**.

Answer (score 11):

SQLite doesn't support `ORDER BY` inside a `GROUP_CONCAT`, but you can actually fake it:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(list_order || ':' || value)
```

Then you need to split the result in code in order to get back your sort and value.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? I don't understand your answer.

Comment: @nowox You cannot sort directly inside a GROUP_CONCAT with SQLite so this command will concatenate the list_order with a separator (here I use ":") and the value. Then when parsing the results (for me I was using Android) you save the data in a list and reorder it based on the list_order.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any indeterminism you can use recursive CTE like this:

```
sqlite> create table t3(pos,col1,col2);
sqlite> insert into t3 values(1,2,'B'),(2,1,'A'),(3,5,'E');
sqlite> select * from t3;
1|2|B
2|1|A
3|5|E
sqlite>
with
  sorted(pos,c1,c2) as (
    select row_number() over (order by t3.pos), -- sorting by first column's value
      t3.col1, t3.col2
      from t3
  ),
  concat(pos,c1,c2) as (
    select sorted.pos,sorted.c1,sorted.c2  -- starting with values for first position
      from sorted
     where sorted.pos=1
     union all
    select sorted.pos,
           concat.c1||','||sorted.c1,  -- adding next value from col1
           concat.c2||','||sorted.c2   -- adding next value from col2
      from concat
      join sorted
        on concat.pos+1 = sorted.pos   -- going through subsequent positions
  )
select c1, c2
  from concat
 order by pos desc
 limit 1;  -- order by desc limit 1 means 'take the row with largest number'

2,1,5|B,A,E
```

Although quite elaborate, this solution guarantees proper sorting and can easily be extended with more columns. The ordering column can have gaps - the `sorted` CTE takes care of making it into a proper integer sequence.

Note that `row_number() over (order by...)` may require a decently recent version of sqlite which supports windowing functions.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
SELECT 
    col1, col3, col3, col4,
    count(col1), count(re.col2) AS cnt,
    GROUP_CONCAT(p.col1) AS "Group1",
    GROUP_CONCAT(p.col2) AS "Group2", 
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN con.col3 is null THEN p.col1 ELSE con.col3 END),
    con.col4, con.col5, p.col3
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM t1 re
        INNER JOIN t2  c  ON (re.col1  = c.col1)
        INNER JOIN t3  p  ON (re.col2  = p.col1)
        LEFT JOIN  t4 con ON (con.col1 = p.col2)
        INNER JOIN  t5 m  ON (m.col1   = c.col5) 
    ORDER BY
        p.col1 ASC,
        p.col2 ASC
)
GROUP BY re.col1
```

I Haven't tested it but if you can share some data...