# display record in asc order using group_concat in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova-2.0.0

I want to write an sqlite query in which a record will be displayed for example i have a contact table and account table i want to fetch a acount name  and contact name from table i want to group_concat the contact name and it should not be repeated so i return a query:

```
select a.account_name, group_concat(DISTINCT c.contact_name) from account_table a join contact_table c on a.account_id = c.account_id;
```

this query execute perfectly know what i want to do is to get group_concat distinct name in asc order so i written the query :

```
 select a.account_name, group_concat(DISTINCT c.contact_name order by c.contact_name) from account_table a join contact_table c on a.account_id = c.account_id;
```

its giving me error at order by

```
10-25 10:29:25.601: E/SQLiteLog(2214): (1) near "order": syntax error
```

can any one tell me how to solve the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sqlite group\_concat ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897352/sqlite-group-concat-ordering)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ORDER BY` clause inside aggregate function call.

Try:

```
select a.account_name, group_concat(DISTINCT c.contact_name)
from account_table a
join contact_table c on a.account_id = c.account_id
order by c.contact_name;
```