# Merging fields in SQlite with dynamic range - HOW?

Tags: sqlite

i have a problem, lets say i make a Select search through several tables and end up with this table:
http://oi59.tinypic.com/2iict36.jpg

And i want it to look like that ( for further processing)

http://oi60.tinypic.com/2vcz0wm.jpg

i could use || operator, but the problem is that i dont know how many diffrent values will be in each subgroup, so i cant really hardcode a few || because sometimes i will need to merge 2 fields, and sometimes 4 etc. Is there any way to merge fields with specified range? or to implement FOR loop, or something similar?

im quite new to SQlite, so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite has the `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregate function.

```
SELECT group,
    subgroup,
    GROUP_CONCAT(value) AS "value"
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY group, subgroup
```

If you need to control the order of values, you'll need to use a subquery like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897352/sqlite-group-concat-ordering).

Comment: ok, thanks, that should work. but my case is a bit more complicated than the example showed. the "value" field comes from different table, and i use its id field to match it with correct group, and subgroup. if i just use this group_concat , is there a way to still provide some requirments (like value.id = group.id AND value.id = subgroup.id)?

Comment: @TymekGłowacki Sure.  Just put the `GROUP BY` after the `WHERE` clause but before any `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Praise the Sun! it worked! thanks a lot! You just saved my ass, and are considered my new personal Jesus :D