# Sqlite Android order by & group_concat

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-order-by, group-concat

I'm using the sqlite3 : 3.8.2  with sqliteman (Ububuntu 14.04) to try the query that I need in my program Android.

Android version 4.0+.

I have 3 table to use to obtain data

I found this problem:

when I use this query in sqliteman

```
SELECT st.nome
AS nome,
st.cognome
AS cognome, 
(SELECT ae.usercode
AS usercode
FROM assenze ae
WHERE st.ultimo_evento = ae.fk_evento)
AS ultimo_evento,
(SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        ev.nome_evento, ", "
    )
    AS nome_evento 
    FROM eventi ev 
    WHERE ev.studente_id = st.id 
)
AS nome_evento
FROM studenti st 
WHERE st.classe_ident ='4297'
ORDER BY st.cognome
```

the output is:

`EP, USC, R1, R, A` ... **perfect for me**

but when I use it in android with `db.rawQuery()` the result is

`A, EP, R, R1, USC` ... **no good for me**

also seems to be the same result of this query (execute in sqliteman and android):

```
SELECT 
st.nome AS nome, 
st.cognome AS cognome, 
ae.usercode AS ultimo_evento, 
GROUP_CONCAT(
   ev.nome_evento, ", "
) 
AS nome_evento
FROM studenti st
LEFT JOIN eventi ev
ON st.id = ev.studente_id
LEFT JOIN assenze ae
ON st.ultimo_evento = ae.fk_evento
WHERE st.classe_ident ='4297'
GROUP BY st.id
ORDER BY st.cognome
```

Probably it's my fault but I'm still trying to find a solution...

Thanks

seems that it works also without ORDER BY ev.data_ora_evento. But in android still not working...

Comment: remove ORDER BY st.cognome from last

Comment: @BSavaliya unfortunately not works... :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sqlite group\_concat ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897352/sqlite-group-concat-ordering)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [group_concat() documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#groupconcat) says:

> The order of the concatenated elements is arbitrary.

However, you could try to force an order by executing group_concat() on a subquery that is sorted:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ev.nome_evento, ", ") AS nome_evento 
FROM (SELECT nome_evento
      FROM eventi
      WHERE studente_id = st.id
      ORDER BY whatever) AS ev
```

Comment: thanks for the link, but if it is arbitrary why in sqliteman work as would and in Android not?

Comment: "Arbitrary" means that any order is correct. Different versions can use different optimizations.

Comment: so the sqliteman give me the correct output only for luck... Thanks
The only way is to correct the order as I need when I obtain the string from the cursor...