# Ensuring ordering for a custom aggregate (windowing?) function in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am working on [sqlite-hashes](https://github.com/nyurik/sqlite-hashes) -- adding hash functions like `md5` and `sha256` to SQLite.

In order to create `sha256_concat(val)` - a hash over a sequence, each value must be consistently ordered.  SQLite does NOT guarantee the order of execution for the regular aggregate functions even if they have an `ORDER BY` in the query, so the result in BOTH of these examples is NOT defined!  (see [group_concat ordering question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897352/sqlite-group-concat-ordering)):

```sql
SELECT sha256_concat(val) FROM tbl ORDER BY val;
SELECT sha256_concat(val) FROM (SELECT val FROM tbl ORDER BY val));
```

I think I can get around it with a custom windowing function, but it has some limitations too:  the aggregation state cannot be "inversed" (once a value is added to the hash, it cannot be removed). It is also harder to "partially-compute" a value (compute an interim hash, and continuing to add values to it).

What would be the SQL to call a window function (use `group_concat` to demonstrate), so that it gets called just like a regular aggregate function - never calling `xValue` and `xInverse` (as described at the end of the [SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#history) page), but still uses `OVER (ORDER BY value)` or a similar construct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SQLite 3.44**

The SQLite version 3.44 supports an ORDER BY clause inside an aggregate function like PostgreSQL.

Your case would look like:

```
SELECT sha256_concat(val ORDER BY val) FROM tbl;
```

doc:       https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html
changelog: https://sqlite.org/releaselog/3_44_0.html