# sql: aggregate functions & string join / concatenation

Tags: sql, postgresql, string, aggregate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to concatenate strings of a string field in a PostgreSQL ‘group by’ query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query)

(I'm using postgres)

Are there any aggregate functions that work on strings?

I want to write a query along the lines of

```
select table1.name, join(' - ', unique(table2.horse)) as all_horses
from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.fk
group by table1.name
```

Given these 2 tables:

```
| table1          |               | table2                    |
| id (pk) | name  |               | id (pk) | horse   |  fk   |
+---------+-------+               +---------+---------+-------+ 
|       1 | john  |               |       1 | redrum  |     1 |
|       2 | frank |               |       2 | chaser  |     1 |
                                  |       3 | cigar   |     2 |
```

The query should return:

```
| name   |   all_horses      |
+--------+-------------------+
| john   |   redrum - chaser |
| frank  |   cigar           |
```

Do functions that along the lines of `join` and `unique` exist in any DBs for strings?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
select table1.name, 
    array_to_string( array_agg( distinct table2.horse ), ' - ' ) as all_horses
from table1 inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.fk
group by table1.name
```

Comment: hmm don't seem to have those functions defined - can you help me close the question as it's a duplicate of 43870 ?

Comment: try to upgrade to 8.4, array_agg is built-in.  regarding closing the question, it needs 5 close, as of now only 1 closed your question.  you can delete your own question

Answer (score 5):

There is a string_agg query in PostreSQL 9.  I have a table of regions and a table of  departments, where there are multiple departments in a region (e.g. France).  My sample query is:

```
select r.name, string_agg(d.name, ',') 
from regions r
join departments d on d.region = r.code
group by r.name
order by r.name;
```

This gives me rows like

```
Picardie Aisne,Oise,Somme
```

Things get a bit messy if you wan to change the order of the aggregated string.  This works, but I have a pathological dislike of any query with distinct:

```
select distinct r.name as region, string_agg(d.name, ',') over w as departments
from regions r
join departments d on d.region = r.code
window w as (partition by r.name order by d.name desc 
    rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
```