# multiple result query as csv string in new column

Tags: sql, linq-to-sql, sql-server-2008

I ve got 3 tables:

User, product user2product

each product has got ID.

Is it possible to write query in which as result I would get 2 columns:

```
UserID, Products
```

And in products column I have all products connected to user by user2product table separated with comma.

Comment: Are you wanting to write this in T-SQL or in Linq?

Answer (score 0):

what SQL-Dialect are we talking about? 
For postgresql, there is a pretty comprehensive answer to be found here:
[How to concatenate strings of a string field in a PostgreSQL 'group by' query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query)

For other SQL-Systems the idea should be pretty much the same. You would have to search for the correct aggregate function, everything else can be done using a simple `group by` directive.

Cheers
Thilo

Comment: Just saw the SQL-Server tag, thus it probably won't be Postgres. Still, the idea should hold.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite possible to do this using in native tsql using the `for xml path` statement as detailed [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/11/25/sql-server-comma-separated-values-csv-from-table-column/)

To access this through linq create a stored procedure on the db, drag it into your dbml file and then call it from the data context like a method.

The code for the sp would look something like this

```
select
    u.userid,
    substring(( select ',' + cast(p.productid as nvarchar(20))
        from
            user2product up inner join
            product p on up.productid = p.productid
        where
            up.userid = u.userid
        for xml path('')),2,2000000) as Products
from
    users u
```