# How to use Concat function in the sfunc parameter while making a aggregate function using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am recently inclined in PostgreSQL and trying to make a ListAggregation function as given [here](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-novice/2003-09/msg00177.php) the only difference being that I am trying to use CONCAT instead of TextCat
.
My function is as under

```
CREATE AGGREGATE ListAggregation(
      basetype    = Text,
      sfunc       = Concat,
      stype       = Text,
      initcond    = ''
  );
```

It is throwing error

```
ERROR:  function concat(text, text) does not exist

********** Error **********

ERROR: function concat(text, text) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
```

what mistake I am making...please help

N.B.~ I have even looked at the example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query)

Thanks

Comment: Indeed there's no `concat(text, text)` function. What's wrong with `textcat(text, text)`?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, what are you palanning to do? There is already a `string_agg()` aggregate function in PostgreSQL 9.0+ ...

Comment: As I am learning (this is my 2nd day) PostgreSQL, i am trying some experiemnt. Just want to know what mistake i am making and how can i rectifiy that.Also i know that textcat precisely takes two arguments while concat accepts multiple. so how to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

You should create state change function **sfunc** to implement an aggregate with the signature: **sfunc( state, value ) ---> next-state**

```
-- sfunc:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION concat(text, text) 
RETURNS text 
LANGUAGE SQL 
AS $$
  SELECT $1||$2;
$$;

-- Aggregate:
CREATE AGGREGATE ListAggregation(
      basetype    = text,
      sfunc       = concat,
      stype       = text,
      initcond    = ''
);

-- Testing:
WITH test(v) AS (VALUES
  ('AAAA'),
  ('BBBB'),
  ('1111'),
  ('2222') )
SELECT ListAggregation(v) FROM test;
```