# Is there a way to optimise an array of subquery in a SQL select?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I currently have two tables

```
question
--------
id
title, character varying

answer
--------
id
question_id
votes, integer
```

I use the following query to return me a list of questions with its corresponding array of votes:

```
SELECT question.id,
    question.title,
    ARRAY(SELECT votes
          FROM answer
          WHERE answer.question_id = question.id)
FROM question
ORDER BY question.id
```

The output looks like:

```
id  | title    | ?column?                       
----+----------+-----------------------------------------------------
100 | How to   | {5,2,7}
101 | Where is | {0}
102 | What is  | {1}
```

The above query can take close to 50s to run with hundred of thousands of questions where each question can have at least 5 answers.  Is there a way to optimise the above?

Comment: Added postgresql tag b/c that looks like postgres-specific syntax. Please feel free remove tag if that's not a correct assessment.

Comment: What is the type of the `votes` column of table `answer`?  Is it an array, or a single integer value?  I assume it's a single `int` value.  Your query doesn't work if it's an array.

Comment: Please add the EXPLAIN ANALYZE of the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend creating an index on your `answer` table, and using your original query.

```
CREATE INDEX answer_question_id_idx ON answer(question_id);
```

Without this index, it will have to do a sequential scan of the entire table to find rows with a matching `question_id`.  It will have to do that for every single question.

Alternatively, consider using a join, as [arc suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9573605/149391).  I'm not an expert in the matter, but I think Postgres will use a hash join rather than multiple sequential scans, making the query faster.  If you want to retain the id/title/array format, use [`array_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
SELECT question.id, question.title, array_agg(answer.votes)
  FROM question
  LEFT JOIN answer ON answer.question_id = question.id
 GROUP BY question.id, question.title
 ORDER BY question.id;
```

However, there's a caveat.  If a question has no answers, you'll get a weird-looking result:

```
 id |       title       | array_agg 
----+-------------------+-----------
  1 | How do I do this? | {3,5}
  2 | How do I do that? | {NULL}
(2 rows)
```

This is because of the `LEFT JOIN`, which creates a `NULL` value when no rows from the joined table are available.  With `INNER JOIN`, the second row won't appear at all.

That's why I recommend using your original query.  It produces the expected result:

```
 id |       title       | ?column? 
----+-------------------+----------
  1 | How do I do this? | {3,5}
  2 | How do I do that? | {}
```

Comment: I already have this index in place and it still takes a while.  I don't see a lot of improvements with the joining method after using `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a join:

```
SELECT question.id, question.title, answer.votes
FROM question
JOIN answer ON answer.question_id == question.id
ORDER BY question.id
```

If you want the output column to contain a concatenated list of all "votes" associated with a question, and you are on Postgres, check out this question: [How to concatenate strings of a string field in a PostgreSQL 'group by' query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the query to produce one row per question, with votes gathered into an array, you can use a join, with [`array_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
SELECT question.id,
    question.title,
    array_agg(answer.votes) as answer_votes
FROM question
JOIN answer ON answer.question_id = question.id
GROUP BY question.id, question.title
ORDER BY question.id
```