# How to GROUP BY and CONCATENATE fields in redshift

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, string-concatenation, amazon-redshift

How to GROUP BY and CONCATENATE fields in Redshift e.g.
If I have table

```
ID   COMPANY_ID   EMPLOYEE
1    1            Anna
2    1            Bill
3    2            Carol
4    2            Dave
```

How can I get result like this

```
COMPANY_ID   EMPLOYEE
1            Anna, Bill
2            Carol, Dave
```

[There are some solutions for PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query), but none of functions mentioned in those answers are available in Redshift rightnow.

Comment: Thanks for clearly identifying that you're using Redshift, not just saying "postgresql".

Comment: Group by: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GROUP_BY_clause.html
Concatenate:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_concat_op.html

Comment: @jenn i don't concat operator can be applied on group by, its more for concatenate fields in same row e.g first & last name as shown in the link u shared. It would be great if can share complete query, if u think its possible.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Well, I am a little late but the [announcement about this feature](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/08/amazon-redshift-now-supports-dynamic-work-load-management-and-list-aggregate-functions/) happened on 3rd Aug 2015.
Redshift has introduced LISTAGG window function that makes it possible to do so now.
Here is a quick solution to your problem - may or may not be useful but putting it here so that people will know!

```
SELECT COMPANY_ID,
       LISTAGG(EMPLOYEE,', ')
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY EMPLOYEE)
OVER (PARTITION BY COMPANY_ID) AS EMPLOYEE
FROM YOUR_TABLE
ORDER BY COMPANY_ID
```

I was happy to see this feature, and many of our production scripts are up for upgrade with all the new features Redshift keeps adding.

[Here is the documentation about the function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LISTAGG.html)

Comment: This is the best answer now that Redshift supports LISTAGG.

Answer (score -1):

== Redshift now has support for this as answered by rohitkulky, do not use this hack ==

Looks like there is no straight forward way to solve this. Here is what i did to solve it, this solution works only when u know how many times ur group by field is repeated e.g in above case its 2, as company_id is being repeated twice. In my case i know this count so this solution works for me, although not very elegant

If group by count is 2

```
select e1.company_id, e1.name || e2.name
from employee e1, employee e2
where e1.company_id = e2.company_id and e1.id < e2.id;
```

If group by count is 3

```
select e1.company_id, e1.name || e2.name || e3.name
from employee e1, employee e2, employee e3
where e1.company_id = e2.company_id and e1.company_id = e2.company_id and e1.id < e2.id and e2.id < e3.id;
```

Comment: How will this work if each result row had different # of concats ?

Comment: OMG, don't use this solution, it doesn't support multiple rows and results